# RegularExpression To Validate A Textbox That Should Allow Only Decimals And Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textbox for 'Area '.I need a regularexpression to validate textbox such that it should allow decimals to enter but no characters.Anyone can help me

Comment: Exactly what format do you want to be valid? "0" "0.0" 0,0" ? Define exactly what you want to allow and we can help you.

Comment: Why not try and convert to a double using your language (e.g. Javascript has some functions to convert strings into numbers)?  This will allow numbers to be localized (for people who use , as a decimal point) and standardized (1E3 => 100; 0x64 => 100, anyone?).

Answer (score 5):

Why not try something that's already built-in to JavaScript: the [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp) function?

Comment: because parseFloat allows all kinds of invalid input that you don't want to see.

Comment: Do you mean that parseFloat("123 foo") == 123 ? Then couldn't you just reject the string if there's whitespace in it?

Comment: @Hirsch, Then parseFloat("123foo") would workfine, I think.  Still, +1, for stealing my answer.  ;P

Answer (score 2):

This regex can validate integers and optional floating point numbers:

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

And instead of using regular expressions, you could use [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp)(value) to check if the numerical value is not a number (NaN).

Comment: +1 for suggesting *actual* number parsing (using a library function).

Answer (score 1):

What is the format of your decimal numbers you will support in your field ?

This ["Simple Regular expression for decimal numbers?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122) StackOverflow question details the possible regex.

```
^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Can ensure a number with one or two decimals, but would not work with `34.` (dot without decimal)

You have lots of possible regex [listed here](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3).

[Unkwntech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412536#412569) is a good complete regexp but would allow 1,15223,11,00.

I would rather use:

```
[-+]?(?:\d(\,?(?>\d{3}[.,]))?)*(?:\.\d*)?
```

Meaning, if you are using a `,`, do so only if it is followed with 3 digits (and then another `,` or a dot for decimal values. That enforces **[digital grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping)**, even though, as pointed out by Paul in the comments, there are locale with more than three digits after a comma...

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
[-+]?(?:\d\,?){0,}(?:\.\d*)?
```

It will match all the following exapmles that have a *:

0*
0.0*
222.0* 
1,000.00*
100,000.00*
-100,000,000,000.12*
asdf
blah.blah

Comment: You can use ? instead of {0,1} to speed up parsing and make the regexp easier to read.

Comment: Good one, I always seem to forget about ?

Comment: -1 for it would allow 1,04400.00 (more than three digits after a ','). See my completed answer for a more robust regex

Comment: I think it's better to just strip the , anyway as they likely will be irrelivent to the actual use anyway.

Comment: It also allows this: 122,2,0,0,2,

Answer (score 0):

For decimal values you would have to allow [.] as well so this should work for you:

```
^[-+]?\d*\.?\d*$
```

(This would also accept + and - symbols)

You can get more specific expression from the RegExLib [here](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3).

Comment: However, the dot matches all characters, like A, B, comma, etc... you want to escape the dot like this: ^[-+]?\d*\.?\d*$

Comment: This will not match numbers in the following notation: 1,000.00

Comment: Unkwnteck: And not 1,0 that is what my country uses, or 1E10. But if that matters to the original poster or not I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "isFinite" function:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isFinite.asp

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm very very late here anyway...

Now we have `<input>` elements of type `number` that are used to let the user enter a number. They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical entries. [More Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

```html
<input id="number" type="number">
```

Answer (score -2):

`'^[0-9]*$'`

Comment: Don't forget - he also wants decimal '.' character

Comment: That can also be a comma "," depending on what country you live in.

Answer (score -2):

If you want decimals, this should work:

```
/^(?:\d+\.?)|(?:\d*\.\d+)$/
```

Comment: This will not match numbers in the following notation: 1,000.00