# RegEx validation of decimal numbers with comma or dot

Tags: regex, validation

How to validate such number input with one RegEx. Strings are not allowed. Two decimal positions after dot or comma.

Example:

> 123.34
>   1.22
>   3,40
>   134,12
>   123

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal or numeric values in regular expression validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{2})?)$/
```

If `$1` exactly matches your input string then assume that it is validated.

Comment: How to allow passing null value in this expression?

Comment: For null values, try this updated regex: `^(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{2})?|)$`. Basically added a `|` towards the end.

Comment: Thank you! That works for decimals, but not for normal integers, like: ex. 453

Comment: That is strange. I have tested the regex [here on JSFiddle for the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PLBex/).

Answer (score 9):

Try This,

```
/^(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{1,2})?)$/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pat = re.compile('^\d+([\.,]\d\d)?$')
re.match(pat, '1212')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x91014a0>
re.match(pat, '1212,1231')
None
re.match(pat, '1212,12')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x91015a0>
```

Comment: is that python?

Answer (score 2):

This is my method to test decimals with `,` or `.` With two decimal positions after dot or comma.

1. `(\d+)` : one or more digits
2. `(,\d{1,2}|\.\d{1,2})?`  : use of `.` or `,` followed by 2 decimals maximum

```js
const regex = /^(\d+)(,\d{1,2}|\.\d{1,2})?$/;

console.log("0.55 returns " + regex.test('0.55')); //true
console.log("5 returns " + regex.test('5')); //true
console.log("10.5 returns " + regex.test('10.5')); //true
console.log("5425210,50 returns " + regex.test('5425210,50')); //true

console.log("");

console.log("10.555 returns " + regex.test('10.555')); //false
console.log("10, returns " + regex.test('10,')); //false
console.log("10. returns " + regex.test('10.')); //false
console.log("10,5.5 returns " + regex.test('10,5.5')); //false
console.log("10.5.5 returns " + regex.test('10.5.5')); //false
```

Comment: `const regex = /^(\d+)(,\d{2}|\.\d{2})?$/;` is better as it allows only 2 digits after the dot or comma.

Comment: @thiebo but what about only one digit after the dot?

Comment: that was not the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TexBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TexBox.TextChanged

    TexBox.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(TexBox.Text, "[^\d\.]", "")

    TexBox.Select(TexBox.Text.Length + 1, 1)

    Dim x As Integer = 0

    For Each c In TexBox.Text
        If c = "." Then
            x += 1

            If (x > 1) Then
                TexBox.Text = TexBox.Text.Substring(0, TexBox.Text.Length - 1)
                TexBox.Select(TexBox.Text.Length + 1, 1)
            End If


        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A more precise validation over thousands separator and prefix signal:

```
const re = /^[-\\+]?\s*((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|\d+)(\.\d{2})?$/
console.log(re.test('-1000000.00')) // true
console.log(re.test('-1,000,000.00')) // true
console.log(re.test('-1000,000.00')) // false
```