# REGEX - Remove decimals from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm looking for some REGEX or some other way in JS how to remove decimal numbers from string.

example input:

```
Mazda 6 2.0 Skyactiv-G Wagon 2018 - Startstop.sk - TEST
Mercedes C63 AMG Sound REVVING 6,3l V8
```

example output:

```
Mazda 6 Skyactiv-G Wagon 2018 - Startstop.sk - TEST
Mercedes C63 AMG Sound REVVING l V8
```

Everywhere I look people want to keep both integers and decimals and just remove strings. But I want to keep all integers just remove decimals (with comma`,` or dot`.`)

I tried something like:

```
var string = "Mazda 6 2.0 Skyactiv-G Wagon 2018 - Startstop.sk - TEST"
parseFloat(string.match(/[\d\.]+/))
// Result is 6
```

But this actually just again remove everything exept integers.

Comment: Match 1 or more digits followed by a decimal part starting either with a dot or comma `\d+(?:[.,]\d)+`

Comment: `6,3l`? This is a lowercase "L" character. Is that intentional or should it be a 1 (digit one)? `re.sub(r"\b\d+[.,]\d+\b ?", "", s)`?

Comment: it is lower case L which refers how many liters it has :)

Comment: @Thefourthbird it seems your answer is yet the only one so feel free to write it as asnwer not a comment and I will accept it

Comment: There are possible duplicate questions like for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886593/regex-validation-of-decimal-numbers-with-comma-or-dot

Comment: @Thefourthbird The main issue with them is that most of them match both ints and floats. Matching `\d+\.\d+` is so evident that no one asks for such patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What to do with it? Shall I post it?

Comment: I would post an answer, just add `\s*` at the start, and suggest `.trim()`ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match bot a dot and a comma using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[,.]` and match 1 or more digits before and after it.

Instead of using `string.match` you can use `string.replace` and using an empty string in the replacement.

Matching optional leading whitespace chars to prevent the double space gaps after removing only the digits:

```
\s*\d+[.,]\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AKzbwT/1)

```js
var string = "Mazda 6 2.0 Skyactiv-G Wagon 2018 - Startstop.sk - TEST"
string = string.replace(/\s*\d+[.,]\d+/g, "");
console.log(string);
```

Or matching 1 or more times a dot or comma followed by 1 or more digits, you can use a repeated non capturing group:

```
\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `\s\d*\.\d+\s`

**Where**

`\s` -  matches any whitespace character

`\d*` -  matches digit (equal to [0-9]) between zero and unlimited times

`\.` -  matches the character `.` literally

`d+` -  matches digit (equal to [0-9]) between one and unlimited times

```js
var string = `Mazda 6 2.0 Skyactiv-G Wagon 2018 - Startstop.sk - TEST
Mercedes C63 AMG Sound REVVING 6,3l V8`
console.log(string.replace(/\s\d*\.\d+\s|\s\d*,\d+/gm, ' '));
```

Comment: result should be `Mazda 6 Skyactiv-G Wagon 2018 - Startstop.sk - TEST` not `2`

Comment: @Andurit, you are right, updated the answer, thanks:)

Comment: Thanks @Mamun but this works only with `.` not with `,`. As my second example `Mercedes C63 AMG Sound REVVING 6,3l V8 `

Comment: @Andurit, I have updated the answer, please check:)

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving you thumbs up for right answer however I decided to accept other answer as it was first :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "Mazda 6 2.0 Skyactiv-G Wagon 2018 - Startstop.sk - TEST";
regex = /\d+(\.\d+)/g;
string = string.replace(regex, "");
console.log(string);
```

result :

```
Mazda 6  Skyactiv-G Wagon 2018 - Startstop.sk - TEST
```

explain :

```
\d :  Matches any digit character (0-9).
+ :   Match 1 or more of the preceding token.
[\.,] : Match "." character  or "," character.
```