# jQuery Match Special Entity Character

Tags: jquery, regex, entity, character

I've got a list of spans, containing numbers. I know how to extract numbers from span, that's easy, but one of my span is ½ character entity.

```
if ($(".XT_Active").html().text() === "&frac12;") {
   //Do stuff
}

if ($(".XT_Active").text() === "½") {
   //Do stuff
}
```

I need it to evaluate to true. Neither of these work.

Any tips?

*SOLUTION*

I moved this to a different, more appropriate function. The above evaluated before the class XT_Active could be given.

It's all good now. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work for me. Perhaps you have whitespace in your span.

http://jsfiddle.net/YL5Aj/

If that's not the issue you could try encoding the html entities using this technique

[HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

http://jsfiddle.net/gZuab/

Answer (score 0):

Hiya Jason **Simple demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9dBG/

Hope this helps the example below is very basic as you i.e. replica of what you were trying. :)

Helpful link: (incase you want to use regex) [Decimal or numeric values in regular expression validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation)

**Quote** (If you will use regex the link above should be helpful and quoting from above link :) But that should be only in case if you are looking to implement regex.

Rest hope this helps you, cheers!

> Further update to handle commas and full stops
>
> If you want to allow a . between groups of digits and a , between the
>   integral and the fractional parts then try:
>
> ^[1-9]\d{0,2}(.\d{3})*(,\d+)?$

**Jquery COde**

```
alert('html value ==>' + $(".XT_Active").html().toString() );
alert('comparision ==>' + ($(".XT_Active").html().toString() == "½"));

if ($(".XT_Active").text() == "&frac12;") {
   // alert('foo ====' + $(".XT_Active").text());
   //Do stuff
}

if ($(".XT_Active").text() == "½") {
    alert('Yay I am inside the if condition' + $(".XT_Active").text());
   //Do stuff
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- <div class="XT_Active"> &frac12;</div> <br /> -->

<span class="XT_Active">½</span> <br />​
```