# Regex matching numbers and decimals

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression that will match the following:

```
.5
0.5
1.5
1234
```

but NOT

```
0.5.5
absnd (any letter character or space)
```

I have this that satisfies all but `0.5.5`

```
^[.?\d]+$
```

Comment: The best answer, rather a research article is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39399503/715269

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a fairly common task. The simplest way I know of to deal with it is this:

```
^[+-]?(\d*\.)?\d+$
```

There are also other complications, such as whether you want to allow leading zeroes or commas or things like that. This can be as complicated as you want it to be. For example, if you want to allow the 1,234,567.89 format, you can go with this:

```
^[+-]?(\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.\d+)?\b$
```

That `\b` there is a word break, but I'm using it as a sneaky way to require at least one numeral at the end of the string. This way, an empty string or a single `+` won't match.

However, be advised that **regexes are not the ideal way to parse numeric strings.** All modern programming languages I know of have fast, simple, built-in methods for doing that.

Comment: It gets a bit sketch when you account for thousands separators since some countries swap the period and commas.

Comment: @TylerCrompton - [Believe me, I know.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5917250/399649) Like I said, as complicated as you want it to be.

Comment: Why doesn't changing the final "+" to "*" allow for a trailing "."? "2.", "+1." etc
https://regex101.com/r/O3eyny/1

Comment: Sorry, seen the bit about "\b". How could I modify it to allow a trailing "." whilst continuing to prevent empty strings and single "+"/"-" triggering it. Should I ask a new question?

Comment: @SamDean - I would suggest a new question, mostly because there are lots of potential variations and I would need specifics. You could take a look at [my other answer as well.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5917250/399649)

Answer (score 19):

Here's a much simpler solution that doesn't use any look-aheads or look-behinds:

```
^\d*\.?\d+$
```

To clearly understand why this works, read it from right to left:

- At least one digit is required at the end.

  `7` works

  `77` works

  `.77` works

  `0.77` works

  `0.` doesn't work

  empty string doesn't work
- A single period preceding the digit is optional.

  `.77` works

  `77` works

  `..77` doesn't work
- Any number of digits preceding the (optional) period.
  `.77` works

  `0.77` works

  `0077.77` works

  `0077` works

Not using look-aheads and look-behinds has the added benefit of not having to worry about RegEx-based DOS attacks.

HTH

Answer (score 13):

Nobody seems to be accounting for negative numbers. Also, some are creating a capture group which is unnecessary. This is the most thorough solution IMO.

```
^[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+$
```

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
^(?!.*\..*\.)[.\d]+$
```

This uses a negative lookahead to make sure that there are fewer than two `.` characters in the string.

http://www.rubular.com/r/N3jl1ifJDX

Comment: This runs through the string twice, though.

Comment: Why would you want to make it this complicated?

Comment: Tyler and Justin - I agree that your method is better, but will leave this up as an alternative.  The lookahead method is nice for checking multiple conditions like this (for example in password validation), but it does over complicate something simple like this, enjoy a +1!

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
^(?:\d*\.)?\d+$
```

Comment: It does, i'm matching \d* in the parenthesis, not \d+

Comment: Looks OK now. I commented before you added the `?`.

Comment: can't remove my previous comment (too little reputation?) which related to another comment (by Tyler, IIRC) that is now gone. I fixed the decimal point issue in response to your first comment.