# Decimal number regular expression, where digit after decimal is optional

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that validates a number, but doesn't require a digit after the decimal.
ie.

```
123
123.
123.4
```

would all be valid

```
123..
```

would be invalid

Any would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The best answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39399503/715269

Answer (score 286):

Use the following:

```
/^\d*\.?\d*$/
```

- `^` - Beginning of the line;
- `\d*` - 0 or more digits;
- `\.?` - An optional dot (escaped, because in regex, `.` is a special character);
- `\d*` - 0 or more digits (the decimal part);
- `$` - End of the line.

This allows for .5 decimal rather than requiring the leading zero, such as 0.5

Comment: @OrangeDog, your original matches more than might be desired. e.g. 'cow3.45tornado' ;)

Comment: @S. Albano, OrangeDog's original regex,`\d+\.?\d*`, would have matched '3.45' in 'cow3.45tornado'!

Comment: Yes, my point was that it might not be a desired behavior given the set of examples Trish gave. OrangeDog then added the second regex, which improved his answer and match that of João, who was getting the upvotes.

Comment: It also matches a single dot which is not a valid decimal number. A better regex would be `/^\d*\.?\d+$/` which would force a digit after a decimal point.

Comment: @Chandranshu and it matches an empty string, which your change would also solve.

Comment: @Chandranshu "doesn't require a digit after the decimal"

Comment: Incorrect. It matches a lone dot, too. And it is NOT the decimal number

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It requires decimals while OP clearly says: optional decimals.

Comment: This will also match 000.2 or the empty string, which are probably not what's desired.

Comment: Why is single dot not a number actually?

Answer (score 155):

```
/\d+\.?\d*/
```

One or more digits (`\d+`), optional period (`\.?`), zero or more digits (`\d*`).

Depending on your usage or regex engine you may need to add start/end line anchors:

```
/^\d+\.?\d*$/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4OwPfvp8lhwV_GZC)

Comment: Yeah, but the top voted answer is wrong, it matches both `.` and the empty string.

Comment: But your answer does NOT take ".1", that is a correct decimal number!

Comment: @Gangnus the question has an odd definition of "decimal number". My answer is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: The question forbids "2..", but not ".2". It is strange only in allowing "2.", that is a bit untraditional.

Comment: @Gangnus Nor does it say that ".digit" should be matched. If they wanted that, then they should have said.

Comment: This is an [evil regex (aka ReDoS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS).

Comment: @EqualityInTech I'm pretty sure it's not - it has no grouping at all.

Comment: Hmm... I think I might not fully understand evil regexes like I thought I did. Sorry.

Comment: Decimals often include negative numbers. Does this match correctly for `-1` and not `-` .

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett this matches exactly what the question specified. As you can see it doesn't include `-` at all.

Comment: What would the regex be if we anted to also accept empty strings? I have an issue where I can't get rid of the last character while backspacing.

Comment: @RaulMarquez simplest way is to add `|` at the end.

Comment: this doesnt allow a `.` after a number, so how do you type `1.`

Comment: @conor909 yes it does, and it explains how. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @OrangeDog it didn’t work in my environment, but it’s possible something else was effecting it

Answer (score 100):

You need a regular expression like the following to do it properly:

```
/^[+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+))$/
```

The same expression with whitespace, using the extended modifier (as supported by Perl):

```
/^  [+-]? ( (\d+ (\.\d*)?)  |  (\.\d+) ) $/x
```

or with comments:

```
/^           # Beginning of string
 [+-]?       # Optional plus or minus character
 (           # Followed by either:
   (           #   Start of first option
     \d+       #   One or more digits
     (\.\d*)?  #   Optionally followed by: one decimal point and zero or more digits
   )           #   End of first option
   |           # or
   (\.\d+)     #   One decimal point followed by one or more digits
 )           # End of grouping of the OR options
 $           # End of string (i.e. no extra characters remaining)
 /x          # Extended modifier (allows whitespace & comments in regular expression)
```

For example, it will match:

- 123
- 23.45
- 34.
- .45
- -123
- -273.15
- -42.
- -.45
- +516
- +9.8
- +2.
- +.5

And will reject these non-numbers:

- . (single decimal point)
- -. (negative decimal point)
- +. (plus decimal point)
- (empty string)

The simpler solutions can incorrectly reject valid numbers or match these non-numbers.

Comment: Best because it matches a number followed by a period (42.).  However there is a bug/false positive as it matches this: 3....3 which can be fixed by adding two more parenthesis to enforce ^$ beginning and end characters: /^([+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+))$/

Comment: Thanks Pete, well spotted. The answer has now been corrected, by adding extra parenthesis so it behaves as intended. It is now written like `^A?(B|C)$`. Previously, it was written like `^A?B|C$` which actually means `(^A?B)|(C$)` which was incorrect. Note: `^(A?B|C)$` is also incorrect, because it actually means `^((A?B)|(C))$` which would not match "+.5".

Comment: This is the best answer.  The other answers don't handle all cases.  I do a similar thing myself except that I use a lookahead to handle the missing-digit cases: /^[+-]?(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(\.\d*)?$/

Comment: That is the only correct regex here. But some people would disagreee with "34.". I would propose + after second d instead of *

Comment: @Gangnus "123." is specifically listed as valid in the question.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes. But here will come other people, too. I think, it would be better to add that variant for "traditional" users. But I am afraid, I had found bad lines: "-0", "-0.", "-0.0", "-.0", and another family: "000", "0001". The second family is easy to manage, but the first one will take many additional symbols.

Comment: This also matches 0000.2, which is probably not what's desired.

Comment: There is an answer by James Miao below that rejects 0000.2 and 01 for example

Answer (score 29):

this matches all requirements:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: For me this is the best answer, since the string: "4." (for example) is not a valid number at least in ruby language. However, the most upvoted answers accepts "4." as a number regex, which is wrong.

Answer (score 21):

Try this regex:

```
\d+\.?\d*
```

> \d+  digits before optional decimal
>   .?  optional decimal(optional due to the ? quantifier)
>   \d*  optional digits after decimal

Comment: Nope, that one does not match `123.`

Comment: Thanks for the note. Modified my regex.

Comment: Indeed, but now you just edited it into what is already posted by someone else. Consider just removing yet another "correct" answer.

Comment: @BartKiers I upvoted this because the answer you're referring to has an additional slash at the beginning so it didn't work for me. This worked.

Comment: @Edison that slash is a regex delimiter: not part of the pattern itself. You will see many answers containing these delimiters.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. Anyway, for someone like me who doesn't know, the answer is good because otherwise I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 8):

I ended up using the following:

```
^\d*\.?\d+$
```

This makes the following invalid:

```
.
3.
```

Comment: You might need slashes depending on which language you're using. For example: /^\d*\.?\d+$/

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did. It's more strict than any of the above (and more correct than some):

```
^0$|^[1-9]\d*$|^\.\d+$|^0\.\d*$|^[1-9]\d*\.\d*$
```

Strings that passes:

```
0
0.
1
123
123.
123.4
.0
.0123
.123
0.123
1.234
12.34
```

Strings that fails:

```
.
00000
01
.0.
..
00.123
02.134
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use this:

```
^\d+(\.\d)?\d*$
```

matches:
11
11.1
0.2

does not match:
.2
2.
2.6.9

Comment: Thanks, very simple and matches what I need

Answer (score 5):

```
^[+-]?(([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9](\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$
```

should reflect what people usually think of as a well formed decimal number.

The digits before the decimal point can be either a single digit, in which case it can be from 0 to 9, or more than one digits, in which case it cannot start with a 0.

If there are any digits present before the decimal sign, then the decimal and the digits following it are optional. Otherwise, a decimal has to be present followed by at least one digit. Note that multiple trailing 0's are allowed after the decimal point.

```bash
grep -E '^[+-]?(([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9](\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$'
```

correctly matches the following:

```
9
0
10
10.
0.
0.0
0.100
0.10
0.01
10.0
10.10
.0
.1
.00
.100
.001
```

as well as their signed equivalents, whereas it rejects the following:

```
.
00
01
00.0
01.3
```

and their signed equivalents, as well as the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

try this. `^[0-9]\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?%?$` it is tested and worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

What language? In Perl style: `^\d+(\.\d*)?$`

Answer (score 2):

What you asked is already answered so this is just an additional info for those who want only 2 decimal digits if optional decimal point is entered:

```
^\d+(\.\d{2})?$
```

^    : start of the string
\d   : a digit (equal to [0-9])
+    : one and unlimited times

Capturing Group (.\d{2})?
?    : zero and one times
.   : character .
\d   : a digit (equal to [0-9])
{2}  : exactly 2 times
$    : end of the string

1 : match
123 : match
123.00 : match
123. : no match
123.. : no match
123.0 : no match
123.000   : no match
123.00.00 : no match

Comment: Does this match negative numbers?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett you need to check for the negative sign so it would be: ^-?\d+(\.\d{2})?$

Answer (score 2):

## Regular expression:

```
^\d+((.)|(.\d{0,1})?)$
```

use `\d+` instead of `\d{0,1}` if you want to allow more then one number use `\d{0,2}` instead of `\d{0,1}` if you want to allow up to two numbers after coma. See the example below for reference:

[image]

or

```
^\d+((.)|(.\d{0,2})?)$
```

[image]

or

```
^\d+((.)|(.\d+)?)$
```

[image]

### Explanation

(These are generated by regex101)

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`)
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- 1st Capturing Group `((.)|(.\d{0,1})?)`
- 1st Alternative `(.)`
- 2nd Capturing Group `(.)`
- `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- 2nd Alternative `(.\d{0,1})?`
- 3rd Capturing Group `(.\d{0,1})?`
- `?` matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- `{0,1}` matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

### Sandbox

Play with regex here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer. I wanted 3 decimal places for road chainages implementation and it helped.

Comment: Dots should be escaped. Otherwise, it will accept any character as the separator e.g. `123a1`.

Answer (score 2):

For those who wanna match the same thing as JavaScript does:

```
[-+]?(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)
```

Matches:

- 1
- +1
- -1
- 0.1
- 1. 
- -1.
- .1
- +.1

[image: Railroad diagram of the regex]

Drawing: https://regexper.com/#%5B-%2B%5D%3F%28%5Cd%2B%5C.%3F%5Cd*%7C%5C.%5Cd%2B%29

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<![^d])\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![^d])
```

clean and simple.

This uses Suffix and Prefix, RegEx features.

It directly returns true - false for IsMatch condition

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d+(()|(\.\d+)?)$
```

Came up with this. Allows both integer and decimal, but forces a complete decimal (leading and trailing numbers) if you decide to enter a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, use Regexp::Common which will allow you to assemble a finely-tuned regular expression for your particular number format. If you are not using Perl, the generated regular expression can still typically be used by other languages.

Printing the result of generating the example regular expressions in Regexp::Common::Number:

```bash
$ perl -MRegexp::Common=number -E 'say $RE{num}{int}'
(?:(?:[-+]?)(?:[0123456789]+))

$ perl -MRegexp::Common=number -E 'say $RE{num}{real}'
(?:(?i)(?:[-+]?)(?:(?=[.]?[0123456789])(?:[0123456789]*)(?:(?:[.])(?:[0123456789]{0,}))?)(?:(?:[E])(?:(?:[-+]?)(?:[0123456789]+))|))

$ perl -MRegexp::Common=number -E 'say $RE{num}{real}{-base=>16}'
(?:(?i)(?:[-+]?)(?:(?=[.]?[0123456789ABCDEF])(?:[0123456789ABCDEF]*)(?:(?:[.])(?:[0123456789ABCDEF]{0,}))?)(?:(?:[G])(?:(?:[-+]?)(?:[0123456789ABCDEF]+))|))
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the regexes here are wrong because they don't consider a lot of edge cases:

- US format of numbers (1,000,000.00) vs. non-US (1.000.000,00)

Assuming only the US format the following numbers are **valid**:

```
0.1
.1

1
12
123

1234
1,234

12345
12,345

123456
123,456

123456789
123,456,789

1.0
12.0
123.0

1234.0
1,234.0

12345.0
12,345.0

123456.0
123,456.0

123456789.0
123,456,789.0

+0.1
+.1

+1.0
+12.0
+123.0

+1234.0
+1,234.0

+12345.0
+12,345.0

+123456.0
+123,456.0

+123456789.0
+123,456,789.0

-0.1
-.1

-1.0
-12.0
-123.0

-1234.0
-1,234.0

-12345.0
-12,345.0

-123456.0
-123,456.0

-123456789.0
-123,456,789.0
```

Assuming only the US format the following numbers are **invalid**:

```
1,000,
1,4
1,00
1,000,1
1,000,10

1.1.
1..1
..1
.1.
-1.1.
-1..1
-..1
-.1.
```

The following regex matches only the valid US numbers:

`^[+-]?((\d*)|(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+))(\.\d+)?$`

if you want non-US numbers:

`^[+-]?((\d*)|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})+))(,\d+)?$`

see https://regexr.com/7guqk

**Edit 1:**

BTW: In some cases, numbers are represented in exponential form

4800 -> 4.80000000000000E+03

My regex doesn't consider those numbers yet.