# Restrict textbox to allow only decimal numbers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, textbox

I have a requirement to make a decimal textbox (Money textbox) which:

1. only allows numbers 0-9 (allow upper numpad keys 0-9 and right numpad
   keys 0-9);
2. allows only one dot which don't appear on start.

Valid:

> - 0.5
> - 1
> - 1.5000

Invalid:

> - .5
> - 5.500.55

Edit

my code is :

```
 private void floatTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !TextBoxValidation.AreAllValidDecimalChars(e.Text);
    }


  public static class TextBoxValidation
{
    public static bool AreAllValidDecimalChars(string str)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        int x = 0;
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            x = (int)c;
        }
        if (x >= 48 && x <= 57 || x == 46)
        {
            ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so you have a requirement. Please show us your effort. And explain to use why your effort is failing.

Comment: here is a similar question with an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914224/wpf-textbox-to-enter-decimal-values

Comment: "And explain to us why your effort is failing"....

Comment: @Mussammil you have the validation outside of the loop. This will only check the last character. Also if it were correct, it will return true if ANY character is ok instead of ALL.

Comment: why cant we use RegEx for comparing the format ?

Comment: @shan ,but what will be the RegEx for this purpose?

Comment: @Bas Brekelmans , yes u r right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow copy and pasting as well you cannot do it with keyboard events. A `TextBox` has a `TextChanged` event which allows you to handle this event appropirately. If you want to block any input that is not a number or dot you could handle it like this:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //get the textbox that fired the event
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox == null) return;

    var text = textBox.Text;
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    //use this boolean to determine if the dot already exists
    //in the text so far.
    var dotEncountered = false;
    //loop through all of the text
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = text[i];
        if (char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            //append any digit.
            output.Append(c);
        }
        else if (!dotEncountered && c == '.') 
        {
            //append the first dot encountered
            output.Append(c);
            dotEncountered = true;
        }
    }
    var newText = output.ToString();
    textBox.Text = newText;
    //set the caret to the end of text
    textBox.CaretIndex = newText.Length;
}
```

Comment: ,thanks for ur response ,this will not solve my requirement 2 (dot never come as first character eg: .5 is invalid instead 0.5 is valid) how to accomplish this too

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your goal by simply implementing two event handlers on a `TextBox`:

```
TextCompositionEventHandler textBox_PreviewTextInput = 
    new TextCompositionEventHandler((s, e) => e.Handled = !e.Text.All(
    c => Char.IsNumber(c) || c == '.'));
KeyEventHandler textBox_PreviewKeyDown = new KeyEventHandler(
    (s, e) => e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space);

textBox.PreviewTextInput += textBox_PreviewTextInput;
textBox.PreviewKeyDown += textBox_PreviewKeyDown;
```

Comment: Try pasting 'Hello World!' into the textbox.

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing that out @BasBrekelmans... I've been using this for years and never noticed that. I would have fixed that using the `TextChanged` event, but not wanting to copy your answer, I'll just keep the -1.