# Awareness of validation errors in view model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, mvvm

I have a textbox whose `Text` property is bound to an integer property in the view model. There is an automatic validation by WPF if the text that is entered by the user is an integer. This functionality is good for me so that I don't need to build additional validation.

Now I have a button whose `Command` property is bound to a command in the same view model and I want to have the `CanExecute` method of that command return false if there are any validation errors.

Is there a possibility to know in the view model if there are any validation errors?

Comment: The easiest Make the integer property nullable `int?` then check the HasValue in the can execute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025757/inotifydataerrorinfo-and-binding-exceptions/30030623#30030623

Comment: You'll have to go with ^ or add code and tell us how you're implementing the validation for the integer property.  `int?` may not work since your validation may not update your backing property if its invalid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827437/binding-validation-haserror-property-in-mvvm

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose this:

- Add a Boolean `HasErrors` property to your view model.
- I your property setters: call one (or more) custom validation methods in your
  viewmodel (then notify the property change)
- In the validation method(s): Set the `HasErrors` property to true
  if there are errors or set it to false if there are no errors.
- In your `CanExecute` method: Check the `HasErrors` property

This steps above are simplied version of implementing the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx) article) which was introduced in .NET 4.5.

If you like you can also completely implement this interface as described in the linked article, but I presume that is more than you need in your case.

With `INotifyDataErrorInfo` you could set and retrieve a list of errors for each of your properties, but this does not seem to be an requirement in your case, that is why I provided a more simple example with just the one flag `HasErrors`.