# WPF Filter Textbox Input with Decimals C#

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I have successfully filtered out anything but digits with the following code. I have utilized the `PreviewTextInput` event to capture the current input:

```
private void NumericValidation(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !_numericValidator.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

`_numericValidator` is defined as `_numericValidator = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");`

This code works perfectly fine to only allow 0-9 to be entered into the textbox.

However, I am looking to allow a single decimal so input can be more precise. I have tested the following regex in RegexBuddy and it works as I expect it should but I can input invalid numbers such as `1..1` and `4.3.5` into the text box.

```
^(?!\.{2,})(?:\d+)?(?:\.{0,1})?(?:\d+)?$
```

Any suggestions as to what I should try next?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF TextBox to enter decimal values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914224/wpf-textbox-to-enter-decimal-values)

Comment: I could not get the accepted answer to work, but this answer further down worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29521786/25515

Answer (score 1):

**Example which I propose below, allows to user input all positive numbers in WPF App.**

- if the first char will be `.`, it will automatically changed to `0.` 
  if the first char will be `0`, and the second will be the other number, it
  automatically add point between.

in XAML :

```
<TextBox Width="100" x:Name="tb" TextChanged="Tb_OnTextChanged" FontSize="20" Margin="15,15,15,15"/>
```

in code:

```
private void Tb_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
      var tbx = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
      string dd = tbx ? .Text;
      if (tbx == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dd)) return;
      var tt = dd.Select(r = > r.ToString()).ToList();
      var myregex = ".1234567890".Select(r = > r.ToString()).ToList();
      var ss = new List < string > ();
      tt.ForEach(o = > {
          if (ss.Contains(".") && o != "." || !ss.Contains(".")) {
              if (myregex.Contains(o))
                  ss.Add(o);
              if (ss.FirstOrDefault() == ".") {
                  ss[0] = "0";
                  ss.Add(".");
              }
              if (ss.Count == 2 && ss.FirstOrDefault() == "0" && o != ".") {
                  ss[1] = ".";
                  ss.Add(o);
              }
          }
      });
      var sbc = new StringBuilder();
      ss.ForEach(u = > sbc.Append(u));
      tb.Text = sbc.ToString();
      tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
}
```