# WPF Decimal Custom Format without Rounding

Tags: c#, wpf, decimal, string-formatting, truncate

MS documentation says it this is not possible... Hoping I missed something in the docs.

want to format decimal number as: -9,999.000
using `StringFormat={}{0:#,0.000}` works, but this "rounds" the input where as I want to "truncate" the input.

To test, in **WPF form applied this string format to a TextBox** bound to a decimal property.

When I enter test values, the actual formatted value doesnt match the expected formatted value as the format string automatically "rounds" the decimal values.

```
Enter     Expected     Actual
1111.999  1,111.999    1,111.999
1111.9999 1,111.999    1,112,000
```

MS documentation clearly states that "0" placeholders will always round.
great, but I dont want that behavior.

Question: is there a format string to show 3 decimal places (with trailing zeros) without using the "0"? or is there a format string that truncates at 3 decimal places instead of rounding at 3 decimal places?

I did try `StringFormat={}{0:#,0.###}` but that removes trailing zeros. (and also `StringFormat={}{F3}`).

```
Enter     Expected     Actual
1111.100  1,111.100    1,111.1
```

closest solution I could find has been [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914224/wpf-textbox-to-enter-decimal-values] but none of the answers really deal with the rounding versus truncate.

**UPDATE**

xaml code where StringFormat is used.

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding 
     TemplateNumber,
     StringFormat={}{0:F3},
     ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
     NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
     Delay=500}"
     />
```

**UPDATE 2**

the IValueConverter Convert function to truncate instead of round...

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   if (value == null)
      return string.Empty;

   int decimalPlaces = 3;  // HACK: hardcoded, needs to be parameter
//   decimal decimalShift = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
   decimal decimalValue = (decimal)value;
//   decimal decimalWhole = Math.Truncate(decimalValue);
 //  decimal decimalFraction = Math.Truncate((decimalValue - decimalWhole) * decimalShift);

   string format;
   string result;

// simpler truncation approach
   decimal d = Math.Round(decimalValue, decimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
   format = "{0:N" + decimalPlaces.ToString() + "}";
   result = string.Format(format, d);

/*
   if (decimalPlaces > 0)
   {
      format = "{0:N0}.{1:" + new string('0', decimalPlaces) + "}";
      result = string.Format(format, decimalWhole, decimalFraction);
   }
   else // whole number only
    {
       format = "{0:N0}"; 
       result = string.Format(format, decimalWhole);
     }
*/
           
  return result;
  }
```

**UPDATE 3**

After further testing... the "displayed value" is now correct, but the "bound property" is not.

the property `TemplateNumber` in the xaml code below has the value entered into the text box, not the value displayed by the text box (as modified by the IValueConverter.

```
<TextBox
  Text="{Binding TemplateNumber, 
  Converter={converters:DecimalConverter Precision=4},
  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
  NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
  Delay=500}"
  />
```

that is:

- Enter value: 1.99999 (5 digits of precision)
- Display value: 1.9999 (4 digits of precision, from IValueConverter)
- TemplateNumber value: 1.99999 (5 digits of precision, unchanged from the value entered)

need to fix the rounding on the convert back too....

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object 
   parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   // note: remove any extra white space
   if (decimal.TryParse(value?.ToString().Replace(" ",""), out decimal d))
   {
       int decimalPlaces = Precision ?? 0;
       decimal result = Math.Round(d, decimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
        return result;
   }
   return null;  // type is decimal? so null is legit
}
```

**UPDATE 4**

added Precision as a property to remove hard coded value.
used MarkupExtension approach. this is really simple to add. cound not figure out how to add multiple properties (xaml barfs: future issue to resolve).

FYI the MarkupExtension to add Precision.

```
public class DecimalConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
  #region Markup Extension

  public int? Precision { get; set; } 

  public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
     return this;
  }

  #endregion // markup extension
...
```

the xaml is as per update 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for example:

```
class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {                        
            return string.Format("{0:F3}", value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(value?.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), out decimal num1))
                return num1;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Add it to your control

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DecimalConverter x:Key="MyDecimalConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Use in textbox

```
<TextBox Text={Binding ...., Converter={StaticResource MyDecimalConverter}}/>
```

Comment: will try that out.

Comment: the IValueConverter approach worked. had to hack the Convert function to deal with the rounding... but it now works. (see update to question).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you right, but if you want to separate default displaying number precision and entered number precision - you should use custom data type (struct or class) to store this state. Also you can test IMultipleValueConverter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: As a second approach (without IMultipleValueConverter) you can evaluate number precision and set it for this number (in parameter value). You need to create some bindable parameter, or data type {value, precision}, and bind TextBox.Text to this value and Parameter in converter to value precision, for example ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=ElemName, Path=ValuePrecision}

Answer (score 1):

The [.Net custom numerical formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#Specifier0) is set in stone, there's nothing you can do about it. Specifically:

> The "00" specifier causes the value to be rounded to the nearest digit preceding the decimal, where rounding away from zero is always used

If you want a different kind of rounding to be applied, you can use [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0), which takes an argument specifying the kind of rounding you'd like (in your case, it looks like `MidpointRounding.ToZero` or `MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity`, hard to tell).

Comment: Rounding has nothing to do with WPF. If you're asking how to go from internal state to display state in WPF, the answer is converters.

Comment: the issue is the WPF textbox input display state value gets rounded (as the user types in the number).

Comment: the MinpointRounding.ToZero is effectively a Truncate to x decimal places... added that to the solution.