# Validate digits between one dot

Tags: regex

Trying to get an expression that will validate all these numbers as true
"1.1", "11.11", "111111.11", "33.1", "333.11"

Basically any integer before and after one dot.

it should fail for these

"1.", ".1", "1.a", "a.a", "a.1", "1111.2323d111", "1111.11111.1111"

I have this expression
"^[0-9]{1,2}([.]{1}[0-9]{1,2})?$

but it failing to detect anything more than 2 digits before and after the dot
so i changed it to
"^[0-9]*([.]{1}[0-9]*)?$
now its validating .1 and 1. too.

Need some combination of both.
please help

Comment: I think you should read on the net how to use the ., + and * characters. [0-9]* will mean "any numbers", [0-9]+ will mean "any numbers, at least one"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal number regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117024/decimal-number-regular-expression)

Answer (score 5):

```
^\d+\.\d+$
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like OP may want the dot and second set of digits to be option.  It would then be `^\d+(\.\d+)?$`, hard to tell from the question though: +1.

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong quantifier at the wrong place.

In:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}([.]{1}[0-9]{1,2})?$
      ^^^^^
```

`{1,2}` means 1 or 2 or the previous character/group/class. If you want to match at least one, then change it to `+`:

```
^[0-9]+([.]{1}[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

And the `{1}` is redundant, you can remove it.

```
^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Comment: Of course, replace the second `{1,2}` with `+` to allow for more digits after the period.