# Regex match collection to decimal array, sort, least value to textbox as decimal in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to use regular expressions to search a string for decimal values.  I want to convert the matches collection to a decimal array. I then want to sort the decimal array and add the lowest decimal value to a textbox using VB.NET.  Is this possible?

Comment: donno about VB syntax but isnt it simple to do with a foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried the following code: dim regex as system.text.regularexpressions.regex = New system.text.regularexpressions.regex("regex code")    Dim match As Match Collection = regex.Matches(TextBox1.Text)      match.toarry(matchArray)

Comment: I have tried the following code: dim regex as system.text.regularexpressions.regex = New system.text.regularexpressions.regex("regex code")    Dim match As Match Collection = regex.Matches(TextBox1.Text)      then I get lost ......  but here is a guide of what I am trying to do  match.Convert.ToDecimal(match)          match.toarry(matchArray)   Array.Sort(matchArray)      matchArray(0) = TextBox2.Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what sort of values you are looking for in your string, but using the regex from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23872060/2278086), you could do something like the following:

```
Dim str = "1.23 ds -100.2 xyz 97.5 1.22 .1"
Dim minVal = Regex.Matches(str, "[+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+))") _
    .Cast(Of Match)() _
    .Select(Function(x) CDec(x.Value)) _
    .Min()
Debug.WriteLine(minVal)
```

Which will print `-100.2`.

The `Cast(Of Match)()` function lets you use the LINQ extension methods on the matches to convert the matched values to decimal using `Select` and then find the minimum value using `Min`.

You can then use `minVal` to set your `TextBox`.