# What's the best way to extract prices from string in one line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, function, match

What's the best way to extract numbers (with dot in between sometimes)from string in one line?

```
var str = "ghjkhjgbkhj123.45khgbkhjgk67   8kjhgkj hg13.99sads";
```

I need an array of `[123.45, 67, 8, 13.99];`

`str.match(/\d+/g)`  returns slightly different results - it doesn't count `"."`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117024/decimal-number-regular-expression-where-digit-after-decimal-is-optional

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use regex as [`/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g`](https://regex101.com/r/zU0fZ9/1)

```js
var str = "ghjkhjgbkhj123.45khgbkhjgk67   8kjhgkj hg13.99sads";

console.log(
  str.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g)
);
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/zU0fZ9/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: What about French and German price format?

Answer (score 2):

`str.match(/[.\d]+/g)` will do what you are asking for. It will allow for more than one dot, so if you want to do something "sensible" given `123.456.789` you will probably want something more complicated -- but in that case you should first figure out exactly *what* more sensible thing you want.