# Regular expression for integer with or without commas

Tags: regex, regular-language

I want to create a regular expression for all sorts of numbers i.e whole numbers (+ve and -ve) and decimal numbers (+ve and -ve) with or without commas.

For e.g the regular expression should cover following number formats.

```
  111     1.11     1,111     1,111.01     1,111,111.01 
 +111    +1.11    +1,111    +1,111.01    +1,111,111.01
 -111    -1.11    -1,111    -1,111.01    -1,111,111.01
```

I have created two regular expressions for handling my scenario.

```
 "^(\\+|-)?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$"   // handles whole numbers with decimals
 "^(\\+|-)?[0-9]\\d*(\\,\\d+)*?$"  // handles whole numbers with commas
```

Now, I want to merge these two regular expressions in order to address my requirements.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal number regular expression, where digit after decimal is optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117024/decimal-number-regular-expression-where-digit-after-decimal-is-optional) [Specifically the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23872060/2064981)

Comment: @ClasG: [That one does not help](https://regex101.com/r/68lRyr/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may merge these 2 patterns of yours like

```
^[+-]?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*(?:[.][0-9]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8zjkUs/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `[+-]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:,[0-9]+)*`  - zero or more sequences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:[.][0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `[.]` - a dot
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end  of string

A more restrictive regex to only allow 3-digits in groupings will look like

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:[.][0-9]+)?$
           ^^^^^         ^^^
```

And if you want to also match whole parts with no thousand separators:

```
^[+-]?(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]+)(?:[.][0-9]+)?$
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this one:

```
 ^[+-]?\d+(,\d+)?(\.\d+)?$
```

You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/oyD3o5/1).

Comment: Not working for more than one comma. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Suniel, you understand you didn't ask for that in the requirements or in the tests, right? Anyway just change `(,\d+)?` with `(,\d+)*` and it will work as expected.

Comment: Actually i added * but in a wrong place. My mistake. Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution that allows only 3 digits between comma:

```
^[+-]?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}|\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : start of string
[+-]?       : optional + or -
\d{1,3}     : 1 to 3 digits (before the first optional comma)
(?:         : non capturing group
  ,\d{3}    : a comma followed by 3 digit
  |         : OR
  \d+       : 1 or more digits
)*          : group present 0 or more times
(?:         : non capturing group
  \.\d+     : decimal dot followed by 1 or more digits
)?          : optional
$           : end of string
```

Comment: Not working for more than one comma. Thanks for your idea with nice description.