# Regex is cutting my string at a dot

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
\s?(\w+)=(\w+)?\s?
```

My input is

```
Brutto=57.800
```

The match is just

```
Brutto=57
```

What can I do to get the following result?

```
Brutto=57.800
```

Comment: change "word" char `\w` to `\S`, which is non-space.

Comment: . . . . .  .  . .  . . . . .  .  . . . . .  .  to `[\w.]+` or better `\d+([.]\d+)?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal number regular expression, where digit after decimal is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117024/decimal-number-regular-expression-where-digit-after-decimal-is-optional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just get all "non-space" chars:

```
\s?(\w+)=(\S*)\s?
```

FYI `(\S*)` has the same effect as `(\S+)?`, but is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like if the value always contains a decimal point `\s?(\w+)=(\d+.\d+)?\s?`

Answer (score 0):

You must handle the dot separately (and escape it with a backslash):

```
\s?(\w+)=(\w+\.?\w+)?\s?
```

Answer (score 0):

If u need just matching u can try `\s?\w+=\d+.\d+\s?`.

If u need grouping also u can try `\s?(\w+)=(\d+.\d+)\s?`

u can also replace \d with \w as \d represents only digits whereas \w represents any Alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you use `\w+` which does not match the dot in `57.800` that so it would match `57`.

If your goal is to match digits after the equals sign with an optional whitespace character `\s?` at the start and at the end, you might use:

[`\s?\w+=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s?`](https://regex101.com/r/CdZrSH/1)

Note that I have not use captured groups `()`. If you want to retrieve your matches using groups, you could use `(\w+)` and `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)`

If the `.800` is optional you could use [`\s?\w+=[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s?`](https://regex101.com/r/c4GF3p/1/)