# regex decimal with negative

Tags: vb.net

with the help of this thread I have tweak a regex for my use.
[Decimal number regular expression, where digit after decimal is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117024/decimal-number-regular-expression-where-digit-after-decimal-is-optional)

So far I have this /^-?[1-9]*$|^,\d+$|^0,\d*$|^[1-9]\d*,\d*$

It works for

- -12
- 0
- 1

It does not work for

- -1,
- -1,1

what I want is:

- -1,1

may a kind soul explain what I am missing or doing wrong with this regex pls? Thank you very much!
I am tweaking it with : https://regexr.com/6sjkh but it's been 2 hours and I still don't know what I am missing. I don't know if language is important but I am in visual basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread you are quoting in your question has already some good answers. However if you do not need to also capture + and do not care about numbers without the leading zero before the comma and no thousand separator I would recommend the following:

/^-?\d+(,\d+)?/

1. The **^** indicates the beginning so that no other text in front is allowed
2. The **-?** is allowing a negative sign ( you need to escape this with \ as - can be a special character
3. **\d+** expects 1 or more digits
4. The last part in parentheses covers the fractional part which as a whole can occure 0 or one time due to the question mark at the end

   - **,** is the decimal separator (if you want to have dots you need to put her ., as a dot is the special character for any character and also needs to be escaped if you look for a real dot)
   - **\d+** is again one or more digits after the comma

I hope this helps a bit. Besides this I can also recommend using an online regular expression tool like https://regex101.com/