# How to check whether the input is a character string or a number using mathematical function in UNIX Shell Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote below bash Shell script to check whether the input value is a character string or a number (using Mathematical function):

```
#!/bin/bash
uniq_value=$1
if `$(echo "$uniq_value / $uniq_value" | bc)` ; then
    echo "Given value is number"
else
    echo "Given value is string"
fi
```

The execution result is as follows:

```
$ sh -x test.sh abc
+ uniq_value=abc
+++ echo 'abc / abc'
+++ bc
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=5): Divide by zero
+ echo 'Given value is number'
Given value is number
```

There is an error like this:

> Runtime error (func=(main), adr=5): Divide by zero.

Can anyone please suggest how to rectify this error?

- The expected result for the input `abc123xy` should be `Given value is string`.
- The expected result for the input `3.045` should be `Given value is number`.
- The expected result for the input `6725302` should be `Given value is number`.

After this I will assign a series of values to `uniq_value` variable in a loop. Hence getting the output for this script is very important.

Comment: A common way to determine if a string is a number is to use regular expression matching.  (The Bash syntax is `[[ ... =~ ... ]]`.)  See, for example, [Decimal or numeric values in regular expression validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2811031/4154375) and [Decimal number regular expression, where digit after decimal is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12117024/4154375).  (Note that many of the answers use reqular expression patterns that don't work with Bash so they will need to be modified.  For example, use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d`.)

Comment: Copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix any errors flagged. If that doesn't resolve your problem, update your question with the corrected code. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce: I get "Given value is a string" no matter what input I provide.

Let's talk about this

```bash
if `$(echo "$uniq_value / $uniq_value" | bc)` ; then
```

You have the `bc` command in 2 sets of command substitutions.

With no backticks or parentheses, this is OK

```bash
echo "$uniq_value / $uniq_value" | bc
```

- if the variable is a number, the output is `1` and the exit status is `0` (success)
- if the variable is zero or not a number, the output (stdout) is empty, the error output (stderr) is the "divide by 0" message, and the exit status is `1` (fail)

With the first level of command substitution,

```bash
$(echo "$uniq_value / $uniq_value" | bc)
```

- if the variable is a number, the shell will attempt to execute the output `1` *as a command*. That may produce nothing on stdout, the error message `sh: 1: command not found` on stderr, and the exit status should be `1`. It won't be an error if you have a command named `1` on your system.
- if the variable is zero or not a number, then the shell will attempt to execute nothing (what was provided to stdout from the command), and it will exit with the command's exit status `1`.

Adding the outer backticks simply repeats the above.
In no case here does the exit status equal to `0`, so "Given value is a number" will not appear.

---

Take not of the syntax of the `if` command: enter `help if` at a bash prompt:

```bash
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
    Execute commands based on conditional.
```

There's no special syntax around the conditional COMMANDS. That's why @munibsiddiqui used this in their answer

```bash
if echo "$uniq_value" | bc &> /dev/null; then ...
```

Simply execute the `bc` command, throw away the stdout, and branch based on the exit status.

Comment: I think that the whole idea of using `bc` to check if a string is a number may not be workable.  `bc` accepts expressions, and some special commands, not just numbers.  For example, `uniq_value=quit; echo "$uniq_value" | bc; echo "$?"` outputs `0`.  The division trick doesn't solve the problem.  `uniq_value='1+1'; echo "$uniq_value / $uniq_value" | bc &> /dev/null; echo "$?"` outputs `0`, but `1+1` is not a numeric string.  In addition, the `bc` on my test system exits with zero status even if given garbage as input.  That may be different with different versions of `bc` though.

Comment: That's all true, but this community wiki answer is more focused on the syntax problems than the actual question. It's too bad that it's filtering up to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You want your script to tell you if the input is a word or a number. Your first attempt tried to do this by dividing the input by itself, but this caused problems when the input wasn't a number.

Here's an improved way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This stores your input into a variable.
uniq_value=$1

# This checks if your input looks like a number.
if [[ $uniq_value =~ ^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
    # If it looks like a number, we double-check with a tool called 'bc'.
    if echo "$uniq_value" | bc &> /dev/null; then
        echo "Given value is a number"
    else
        echo "Given value is a string"
    fi
else
    echo "Given value is a string"
fi
```

Here's what this script does differently:

First, it checks if your input is a number (including decimals) using a simple rule. If it passes this check, it moves to the next step.
Then, it uses a program called bc to double-check if it's really a number. If bc doesn't complain, then your input is definitely a number.
If your input doesn't look like a number from the start, or if bc can't handle it, the script decides it's a word and tells you so.

This way, your script can correctly identify inputs like "abc123xy" as words and "3.045" or "6725302" as numbers, just as you wanted.

**Update: Aserre & oguzismail raised a valid point in the comment. Here is the revised version**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Grab what you type and save it.
uniq_value=$1

# Now, we check if what you typed looks like a number.
# This means it could be a whole number, a decimal, or even a negative number.
if [[ $uniq_value =~ ^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
    echo "Given value is a number"
else
    echo "Given value is a string"
fi
```

Comment: You don't need `bc` if the string matches the regex though. It's only going to add potential errors if `bc` crashes or overflows/undeflows

Comment: @Aserre bc doesn't overflow/underflow

Comment: @oguzismail isn't bc linked one way or another to c's `DBL_MAX` constant ? If not, that's pretty neat. Anyway, the call to `bc` still seems redundant if you check the input via a regex beforehand

Comment: @Aserre  script has been updated.

Comment: Note that the code does not recognize numbers that begin or end with `.` as numbers.  Examples include `.5` and `5.`.  `bc` accepts such numbers.

Comment: @Aserre No, it's not. bc is an arbitrary precision calculator.

Comment: `looks_like_a_number() { [[ $1 =~ ^[+-]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$ ]]; }`