# How to avoid unwanted characters in UITextfield?

Tags: ios, validation

In my textfield it should allow both positive and negative decimal values. So I used the regex

```
#define FLOAT_REGEX @"-[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?"

-(BOOL) checkForDecimalValue:(NSString *) string
{
NSPredicate *confidenceTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",FLOAT_REGEX]; 
return [confidenceTest evaluateWithObject:string]?YES:NO;
}
```

But it is not accepted if I enter only positive values without any decimal point (for ex 100,200, etc). It should allow positive values and integer also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace the line use the following:

```
#define FLOAT_REGEX @"^[-]?[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)?$"
```

Hope this helps in what you want. Check its validity from [here](http://www.regextester.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used this Regex am getting warning as Unknown escapeSequence \d. Also it is not allowing positive values.

Comment: edited and changed to new expression.. please check if this works.. works for me

Answer (score 0):

A digit in the range 1-9 followed by zero or more other digits:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

To allow numbers with an optional decimal point followed by digits. A digit in the range 1-9 followed by zero or more other digits then optionally followed by a decimal point followed by at least 1 digit:

```
^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

Notes:

The `^` and `$` anchor to the start and end basically saying that the whole string must match the pattern

`()?` matches 0 or 1 of the whole thing between the brackets

Update to handle commas:

In regular expressions `.` has a special meaning - match any single character. To match literally a `.` in a string you need to escape the `.` using `\.` This is the meaning of the `\.` in the regexp above. So if you want to use comma instead the pattern is simply:

```
^[1-9]\d*(,\d+)?$
```

Further update to handle commas and full stops

If you want to allow a `.` between groups of digits and a `,` between the integral and the fractional parts then try:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{3})*(,\d+)?$
```

i.e. this is a digit in the range 1-9 followed by up to 2 other digits then zero or more groups of a full stop followed by 3 digits then optionally your comma and digits as before.

If you want to allow a `.` anywhere between the digits then try:

```
^[1-9][\.\d]*(,\d+)?$
```

i.e. a digit 1-9 followed by zero or more digits or full stops optionally followed by a comma and one or more digits.

ref : [Decimal or numeric values in regular expression validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation)

hope it helps, happy coding :)