# Finding non-numeric data in a data frame or vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have read in some lengthy data with `read.csv()`, and to my surprise the data is coming out as factors rather than numbers, so I'm guessing there must be at least one non-numeric item in the data. How can I find where these items are?

For example, if I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,"five",6,7,8,"nine",10))
```

I would like to know that rows 5 and 9 have non-numeric data. How would I do that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,"five",6,7,8,"nine",10))
```

The trick is knowing that converting to numeric via `as.numeric(as.character(.))` will convert non-numbers to `NA`.

```
which(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df[[1]]))))
## 5 9
```

(just using `as.numeric(df[[1]])` doesn't work - it just drops the levels leaving the numeric codes).

You might choose to suppress the warnings:

```
which.nonnum <- function(x) {
   which(is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(x)))))
}
which.nonnum(df[[1]])
```

To be more careful, you should also check that the values weren't NA before conversion:

```
which.nonnum <- function(x) {
   badNum <- is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(x))))
   which(badNum & !is.na(x))
}
```

`lapply(df, which.nonnum)` will report 'bad' values for all columns of the data frame.

Comment: Why can't you use `is.numeric()`?

Comment: because `is.numeric()` applied to a factor simply drops the levels.

Comment: The answer helps me to find inconsistence notations of missing values in source data. I have data where the missing values were represented by "-" or "x". For example,  `df <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4,"-",6,7,8,"x",10)); df %>% filter(value %>% as.numeric() %>% is.na()) %>% count(value) ` can find what are the non numeric data in the column.

Comment: If the dataframe has multiple columns, can it be adapted to detect non-numeric and if found, return the row, column of their locations?

Comment: Sure (trivially, `lapply(df, which.nonnum)`).  If you like you could ask that as a new question, linking back to this one.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative could be to check which entries in the vector contain any characters other than a number:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,"five",-6,7.1,-8.059,"nine",10))
which(!grepl('^-?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\\.[0-9]+)?$',df[[1]]))
## 5 9
```

Comment: This caret in the regex should be inside the character class. Also, you might consider changing the regex to `[^0-9.]` to allow for decimals.

Comment: and `[^0-9.-]` for minus signs? (I'm not quite sure how regex distinguishes `-` as character from `-` as range separator)

Comment: Thanbks @Ashish and Ben. I think checking for decimals and negative numbers is a good idea, however the resulting regex Ben proposed will also match invalid elements. So the answer now includes a regex string from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39399503/8037249