# Changing the category of a variable in R: Warning message

Tags: r

I'm trying to change the participants' Age variable (in my dataset) that's showing as character (rather than numeric) using the following code..

```
bwdata6 <- bwdata6 %>% mutate(Age <- as.numeric(Age))
```

I get the following warning message when I run the code...

```
Warning messages: 1: Problem with mutate() input ..1. i NAs introduced by coercion
Input ..1 is Age <- as.numeric(Age). 2: In mask$eval_all_mutate(dots[[i]]) : 
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: That means that at least one of your values is not very numeric looking. You can find the problematic values using the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196106/finding-non-numeric-data-in-an-r-data-frame-or-vector

Comment: `mutate` doesn't use `<-` assignments, it uses `=` to attach values to arguments.

Comment: I checked the link, how do I apply the code to my dataset to figure which values are probllematic? The code is as follows: which.nonnum <- function(x) {
  Age <- is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(x))))
  which(Age & !is.na(x))

Comment: @user2554330 so just changing <- to = should solve the problem? I just tried it (i.e., Age = as.numeric (Age)), it didn't work!

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for the link Ronak, next time I'll try to make my questions more easier to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

Without a `warning` you may use `gsub`.

```
d$x.num <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", NA, d$x))
```

to identify those values that become `NA` accordingly, :

```
grep("\\D", d$x)
# [1] 2 4 6

d
#   x x.num
# 1 1     1
# 2 A    NA
# 3 2     2
# 4 B    NA
# 5 3     3
# 6 C    NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1, "A", 2, "B", 3, "C"))
```

Comment: So applying gsub to my data do I run the following code... d$x.num <- as.numeric(gsub("\\Age", NA, d$x))

Comment: @DrZaheer `as.numeric(gsub("\\D", NA, d$Age))`, the `"\\D"` is a regular expression for "any non-digit", read `?gsub` and `?"regular expression"`.