# Create list of all items in a data frame which can't be converted to number

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric

I have a large data set where I want to convert variables to numeric. The data has been entered in excel with some items given a name which corresponds to a number (so data is type `character`), but sometimes this has been mis-spelt, or unusual terminology used. **I need to identify all items in the dataframe which are strings which could not be converted to numeric**.

Here is MWE:

```
num = data.frame(var1 = c("2", "green", "5"),
                 var2 = c("blue","4",  "9"),
                 var3 = c("ble", "4", "1"),
                 var4 = c("5", "7", "big"))
```

**In this example the output would be `c("green","blue","ble", "big")`**

I will then convert these to the relevant number as follows:

```
num%>%
  mutate(across(contains("var"), ~ str_replace_all(., c("green" = "3", "blue|ble" = "3.5", "big" = "10"))))
```

before converting to numeric

Comment: You could try `unique(unlist(num)[is.na(as.numeric(unlist(num)))])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196183/4083743 might help

Answer (score 2):

Unlist to create an atomic vector then select the elements with contain anything that is not a number.

```
grep("\\D", unlist(num, use.names = FALSE), value = TRUE)
# [1] "green" "blue"  "ble"   "big"
```

If you have decimal separators "." then the above will fail and smth like the following should be used

```
grep("^(\\d|\\.)+$", unlist(num, use.names = FALSE), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
```

Then you can create a lookup vector to replace them and convert to numeric:

```
lut = c("green" = 10, "blue" = 20, "ble" = 30, "big" = 40)
num[] <- lapply(num, \(x) as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("\\D", x), lut[x], x)))

#   var1 var2 var3 var4
# 1    2   20   30    5
# 2   10    4    4    7
# 3    5    9    1   40
```