# How can a string.match include decimal points?

Tags: string, lua

So I am trying to get string.match to not only get '%d+'(any string of strait digits) but I want it to include decimal points IF they are present. I can't make the pattern '.%d+' or '%d+.%d+' because then those would detect any punctuation and wouldn't get a plain non decimal number

I'm so lost here

Comment: You have to try regular expressions from answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation and remove this question - it's effectively a duplicate, but for particular technology (lua)

Comment: @PetroKorienev Lua does not have regex in traditional sense. Lua patterns will not recognise `(%.%d+)?` (where `%` acts the same as `\ ` does in normal patterns)

Comment: Oh, sorry then :( Then, maybe it has sense to try something like http://rrthomas.github.io/lrexlib/ to get power of POSIX regexps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the pattern `"(%d*%.?%d+)"`

It matches:

- 12345
- 12.345
- .12345

But not:

- 12345.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `[%d%.]+` if you are sure that decimal points only appear with numbers. This pattern matches

- `12`
- `12.`
- `12.3`
- `.3`

but also

- `.` without any nearby digits