# Java regex to check if string is valid number format (comma and decimal point placing)

Tags: java, regex, validation

```
1000 - valid
1,000 - valid
1,000.00 - valid
1000.00 - valid
1000.00.00 - invalid
1,0.00 - invalid
1,000,00.00 - invalid
1,000,000.12 - valid
```

no of decimal places can be unlimited

I've been trying to find the right regex pattern, can't seem to find one that will accomodate all validations. Can anyone help

the pattern ^[1-9]\d{0,2}(.\d{3})*(,\d+)?$ did not work for me, based from the similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal or numeric values in regular expression validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation)

Comment: the pattern ^[1-9]\d{0,2}(.\d{3})*(,\d+)?$ did not work for me, based from that similar thread

Comment: @Alain Del Rosario try using ^[1-9]\d*(\,\d+)?$ . You can try the regex script with sample input on this site http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: @Arthur Decker did not work

Comment: i think validations from that link treats commas as required not optional

Comment: If there are thousand separators before the decimal point, do they need to be there after the point too? Are both 1,111,111.111,111,1 and 1,111,111.1111111 valid?

Comment: @AlainDelRosario, please remember to accept an answer if you find one of the four acceptable. Excuse me for mentioning, but it seems you were good at accepting answers in January, I hope you are not starting to forget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should try this expression:**

```
^\d{1,3}|\d(([ ,]?\d{3})*([.,]\d{2}+)?$)
```

With this expression is covered with the scenarios raised.

**Here the complete example:**

```
public class Decimal {

    private static String REGEX = "^\\d{1,3}|\\d(([ ,]?\\d{3})*([.,]\\d{2}+)?$)";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data[] = {"1000", "1,000", "1,000.00", "1000.00", "1000.00.00", "1,0.00", "1,000,00.00", "1,000,000.12"};

        Pattern.compile(REGEX);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].matches(REGEX)) {
                System.out.println(data[i] + " - valid");
            } else {
                System.out.println(data[i] + " - invalid");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**The output:**

- 1000 - valid
- 1,000 - valid
- 1,000.00 - valid
- 1000.00 - valid
- 1000.00.00 - invalid
- 1,0.00 - invalid
- 1,000,00.00 - invalid
- 1,000,000.12 - valid

Answer (score 3):

This is one of possible regexes you are looking for:

```
^\d{1,3}([ ,]?\d{3})*([.,]\d+)?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/T8tcDP/1

Comment: This pattern shows "10,00" as valid and ".05" as invalid.

Comment: Also negatives dont work with this.

Answer (score 0):

This would match your numbers there `(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?|\.\d{2})`
It would also match `.00` just incase. If you don't want it to, just remove
the `|\.\d{2}` part.

Add your own boundary constructs as needed `^$` or `\b`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      \d+ 
      (?: , \d{3} )*
      (?: \. \d{2} )?
   |  \. \d{2} 
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

```
^[1-9]((\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*(\.(\d{3},)*\d{1,3})?)|(\d*(\.\d+)?))$
```

A number either has separators for every 3 digits or it hasn’t (no middle forms). It either has a decimal point and at least one digit after it, or it hasn’t. In all cases does it start with a non-zero digit.

Remember that a dot (period, `.`) has a special meaning in regex and therefore needs to be escaped to get a literal point.

Answer (score 0):

this solution work also for one digit after dot:

```
^\d{1,3}(,{1}\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

- 100.1 - valid
- 1.11 - valid
- 1,000123,123.1 - invalid

good luck.