# Java number format validation

Tags: java, validation, number-formatting

Can you please advice solution in Java to validate number formats.
As input param I receive String. For example, there is Europe format: 1.234,56
Then I do parsing:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).parse(value)
```

But before parsing I need validation.
Example of input data:
1..234,,56 - shouldn't be valid but it parsable

Comment: Why should it not be valid? According to what rule? If your rule is not "what is parseable is valid" then *you* need to define what is valid, e.g. with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with building your regular expression to check for the format having commas or decimals in a string.
Also take reference from the regular expression like :
^\d{1,3}|\d(([ ,]?\d{3})*([.,]\d{2}+)?$)

You can also have a look to this one: [Java regex to check if string is valid number format (comma and decimal point placing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822629/java-regex-to-check-if-string-is-valid-number-format-comma-and-decimal-point-pl)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many possible solutions. But for this situation it would be good to use exceptions. When it is not possible to convert the string into a number, basically write a message to the user that he wrote the wrong number and ask him to enter the new one. For selecting the correct number type, you can use `overloading`.

```
try {
    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).parse(value)
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("The number entered is invalid.");
    // Enter the new number code
}
```