# How to check sign decimal used in string number

Tags: java, regex

How to check if a string number has a decimal point or comma

example :

i have tried with this, but not work

```
String strNumber="1,431,936.00"; //decimal sign uses a dot
  
String strNumber2="1.431.936,00"; //decimal sign using commas
  
if(strNumber.matches("^[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*")){
    System.out.println("sign decimal used dot ");
}
   
if(strNumber2.matches("^[0-9]*\\,?[0-9]*")){
     System.out.println("sign decimal used commas ");
}
```

Thanks

use matches for checking

Comment: Using the REGEX from accepted answer [Java regex to check if string is valid number format (comma and decimal point placing)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42846788/1248974) works for the `dot` version, add a second REGEX pattern replacing the dot with a comma, will match the `commas`.

Comment: What output do you want if the string uses neither commas or periods? Example: "1"

Comment: Also, "1.234" should be indeterminable. There probably needs to be a few default cases.

Comment: Why using `regex` for this? Why not [`contains()`](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-contains)?

Comment: To elaborate on @ODDminus1's example: Is `123.345,789` using dots or commas as a decimal sign and why?

Comment: What about `123,456`? How do you know if that is 123 thousand and 456, or 123.456?

Comment: The correct way to deal with this is not to expect both formats, but rather to use a NumberFormat based on locale of the user.  You can easily do this with `NumberFormat.getInstance()`, which automatically uses the current system Locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\d([.,]?\d)*
```

You can see it working [here.](https://regex101.com/r/HHlnvG/1)

It will allow you to embed individual comma or dot between two digits, but not at the ends or two of them together.  If you don't mind, then

```
[\d,.]*
```

is easier.  Any sequence of dots, digits or commas will match as a group.

If you want to separate three digit groups before the comma only, and no groups after, then

```
([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*|0)\.\d*|([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*|0)?\.\d+
```

See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/mFJFFO/1).

Answer (score 0):

Will this example help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strNumber="1,431,936.00"; //decimal sign uses a dot

    String strNumber2="1.431.936,00"; //decimal sign using commas

    if(strNumber.matches("^[0-9,]+\\.\\d+$")){
        System.out.println("Sign decimal used dot, see: " + strNumber);
    }

    if(strNumber2.matches("^[0-9\\.]+\\,\\d+$")){
        System.out.println("Sign decimal used comma, see: " + strNumber2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sign decimal used dot, see: 1,431,936.00
Sign decimal used comma, see: 1.431.936,00
```