# What is the Regex for decimal numbers in Java?

Tags: java, regex, real-number

I am not quite sure of what is the correct regex for the period in Java. Here are some of my attempts. Sadly, they all meant any character.

```
String regex = "[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*";
String regex = "[0-9]*['.']?[0-9]*";
String regex = "[0-9]*["."]?[0-9]*";
String regex = "[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*";
String regex = "[0-9]*[\\.]?[0-9]*";
String regex = "[0-9]*.?[0-9]*";
String regex = "[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*";
String regex = "[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*";
```

But what I want is the actual "." character itself. Anyone have an idea?

What I'm trying to do actually is to write out the regex for a non-negative real number (decimals allowed). So the possibilities are: 12.2, 3.7, 2., 0.3, .89, 19

```
String regex = "[0-9]*['.']?[0-9]*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

String x = "5p4";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

The last line is supposed to print false but prints true anyway. I think my regex is wrong though.

Comment: In all of your examples you've made it optional with `?`. Is that what you want?  The period is just `\.` you don't need brackets or anything else.

Comment: try `System.out.println("scary.wombat".replaceAll("\\.", "_"));`

Comment: If all you want is a period, why are there numbers around it?

Comment: please mind the difference between `matcher.find()` and `matcher.matches()` - `find()` does not work against the complete region applied.

Comment: The best answer, rather a research article is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39399503/715269

Answer (score 9):

> Update

To match non negative decimal number you need this regex:

```
^\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*$
```

or in java syntax : `"^\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d*$"`

```
String regex = "^\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d*$"
String string = "123.43253";

if(string.matches(regex))
    System.out.println("true");
else
    System.out.println("false");
```

> Explanation for your original regex attempts:

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*
```

with java escape it becomes :

```
"[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*";
```

if you need to make the dot as mandatory you remove the ? mark:

```
[0-9]*\.[0-9]*
```

but this will accept just a dot without any number as well... So, if you want the validation to consider number as mandatory you use + ( which means one or more) instead of *(which means zero or more). That case it becomes:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial understanding was probably right, but you were being thrown because when using `matcher.find()`, your regex will find the first valid match within the string, and *all* of your examples would match a zero-length string.

I would suggest `"^([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|\\.[0-9]+)$"`

Answer (score 1):

If you on Kotlin, use ktx:

```
fun String.findDecimalDigits() =
    Pattern.compile("^[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*").matcher(this).run { if (find()) group() else "" }!!
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 ways to match a literal `.`. One is using backslash-escaping like you do there `\\.`, and the other way is to enclose it inside a character class  or the square brackets like `[.]`. **Most of the special characters become literal characters inside the square brackets** including `.`. So use `\\.` shows your intention clearer than `[.]` if all you want is to match a literal dot `.`. Use `[]` if you need to match multiple things which represents match this **or** that for example this regex `[\\d.]` means match a single digit or a literal dot

Answer (score 0):

I have tested all the cases.

```
public static boolean isDecimal(String input) {
        return Pattern.matches("^[-+]?\\d*[.]?\\d+|^[-+]?\\d+[.]?\\d*", input);
}
```