# Extracting numerical vector from string in R

Tags: r, string, character

I have the following  string :

```
G="[-2.798,-1.805)"
```

I need only the numeric vector `[1] -2.798 -1.805` so I try

```
as.numeric(unique(unlist(regmatches(G, gregexpr("[0-9]+", G)))))
```

get: `[1]   2 798   1 805`
but, I don't know what else I could do.
Thanks so much

Comment: Minor tweek to your regex: `as.numeric(unique(unlist(regmatches(G, gregexpr("-?[0-9.]+", G)))))`. The `?` says 0 or 1 matches and the "." is matched literally in the character class.

Comment: Your regex only matches integers. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation. But do you really need regex for this? Could just remove the first and last character, then read as array. Would be much faster

Comment: `as.numeric(strsplit(substring(G, 2, nchar(G) - 1), split = ",")[[1]])`

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be simplified a bit by removing the `unique` (although processing a bunch of `cut` boundaries might still need that function). The problem you currently face is not including minus-signs and periods. They can be used in character-class arguments

```
 as.numeric( unlist(regmatches(G, gregexpr("[-.0-9]+", G))))
[1] -2.798 -1.805
```