# Angular forms validation on numbers

Tags: angular

I just did my first forms validation in Angular and it works really nice. Some of my input must be numbers only, and I would expect that to be fairly easy. However I only found some pretty complex extensions can this be true? Is there not an easy way to a simple validation for numbers?

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   name: ['', Validators.required],
   type: ['', Validators.required],
   imo: ['', [Validators.required]],
   dwt: ['', Validators.required],
   built: ['', Validators.required],
   yard: ['', Validators.required],
   flag: ['', Validators.required]
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your input to be numbers only, just use the right type of input in your template:

```
<input type="number" formControlName="built" ... >
```

You don't need to add a validator for this if you can restrict the input to numbers only.

However, if you can't change the input type, then you can use the `pattern` validator with a regex to check if the value is a number:

```
Validators.pattern(/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/)
```

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996054/angular-5-validators-pattern-regex-for-only-numbers) for more info about the use of the pattern validator for numbers.

You can also wrap this into a custom validator:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

function numberOnly(control: FormControl) {
  const regex = /^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/;
  return regex.test(control.value) ? null : { number: false };
}
```

which you can use it like this:

```
built: ['', Validators.required, numberOnly],
```

Comment: Thanks, just perfect. Especially just setting type to number! I will save the other option too. Highly appreciated!