# Pattern matching in validation

Tags: java, pattern-matching

As Given below I have to write one method in java before calculation  performing. I am going to check if that string contains only numbers, but if I am going to enter floating points values it will not going  to validate it.

Please suggest me right source code for it.

```
if (Purchase_Paid.getText().matches("[0-9]+")) {
    Global_Total = Float.parseFloat(Purchase_Amount.getText());
    Globle_paidAmount = Float.parseFloat(Purchase_Paid.getText());
    GlobleOutStandingAmount = (Global_Total - Globle_paidAmount);
    Purchase_Outstanding.setText(String.valueOf(GlobleOutStandingAmount));
} else {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.setTitle("Validation");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Please enter only numbers in Paid fields");
    alert.showAndWait();

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal or numeric values in regular expression validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation)

Answer (score 0):

you check if string is numeric like this

```
if (Purchase_Paid.getText().matches("^[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$")){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression `[0-9]+` will only match for numbers in your text. If you want to allow floating point numbers too, then use following regex

`[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+`

```
if (Purchase_Paid.getText().matches("[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+")) {
    //Take Necessary action
}
```