# Match only numbers including decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field I want the input value to be only numbers and decimals nothing more but the problem is that when I type the Unicode characters and letters and semicolons the input value excepts it how do I achieve that.

```
          let newValue = item.value.replace(new RegExp(/[a-z] && [@!#$%^&*()_+}{}|:,=] /,'ig'), "");
            item.value = newValue;
```

Comment: Is the value entered interactively? Or do you want to parse existing data? What needs to happen if the number isnt valid?

Comment: I need the value to be entered interactively.

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Validation on input:

```js
var org = '';
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].oninput = function(e) {
  var val = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  
  if(val == '' || val.match(/^([0-9]*\.)?[0-9]*$/)) {
    org = val;
  } else {
    val = org;
  }
  
  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = val;
}
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].oninput();
```

```html
Number here: <input value="1.23" type="text" /><br />
```

Comment: `0b0`, `0o0` and `0xA` are also numbers :)

Comment: Ye, but i guess its an xy problem. Need more info - im aiming at the the desired solution not the asked :P

Comment: true that. just wanted to add in on the valid cases

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only accept number and decimals for your input you can do either of these two ways:

1. Use `input` type `number`.

```html
<input type="number"/>
```

2. Use a `regex` like below, which accept only numbers and decimals:

```js
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

**NOTE:** If you want to use the comma (and `.` in any place) as input also, you can use this one (according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811058/11908502)):

```js
^-?[0-9][\.\d]*(,\d+)?$
```

Comment: why `[1-9]`? values like `0.5` won't match. nor `-1`, `.5`, or `1.`

Comment: i know what `[1-9]` is, i'm questioning the use of it because it prevents `0.5` from matching

Comment: your last regex matches `1...2...3`

Comment: @PhuNgo Yea, because it will allow entering `.` in any place according to the shared post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function scrubInput() {
  let numberInputElem = document.getElementById('numberInput');

  const regex = /[^0-9\.]/
  let newValue = numberInputElem.value.replace(regex, "");
  numberInputElem.value = newValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numberInput" oninput="scrubInput()"/>
```

Comment: non-number values like `1.2.3` or `..11..` are accepted. and pasting text inside does not trigger scrubbing

Comment: Hey can you remove if the period is repeating like 1..2 that's not good but instead like this 1.2.