# Don't let the decimal point repeat more than one time inside input value

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have an input value that excepts decimal numbers but the problem is that the decimal point or the period point repeat more than one time inside the input value for example 1.2.3 instead of this 1.23 thank you.

```
           let input = document.querySelectorAll("input")

              let arr = []

           function period_noRepeat(x){
              const result = []
             const input = Array.isArray(x)? x: x.split('')

             for(let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i){
             if(input[i] == input[i + 1] && input[i] != 1 * input[i]) continue
           result.push(input[i])
             }

            return result;
            }

            const regex = /[^0-9\.]/
           input.forEach(function(item){
              item.addEventListener("input",function(e){

              item.value = item.value.replace(regex,"")

             arr = item.value.split("")


             item.value = period_noRepeat(arr).join("")




         })



        })
                <input type="text" class="dividend" >
               <input type="text" class="divisor" dir = "rtl">
```

Comment: Did you try by using `<input type="number" ... >` instead of `<input type="text" ... >`?

Comment: But that's not what I want that one is boring.

Comment: Well, that will fix the issue, if that's not good enough, I'm creating a code for that, you can see in few seconds as answer in this page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match only numbers including decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706218/match-only-numbers-including-decimals)

Comment: `item.value = item.value.replace(/(\.[^.]*)\./, "$1").replace(/^\.|[^\d.]/, "").replace(/^0[^.]/, "0")`

Comment: Or with backreferences just: `item.value = item.value.replace(/(?<=\..*|^)\.|(?<=^0)\d|[^\d.]/, "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature from the callback associated to the events, to avoid the event's effect: `event.preventDefault()`. You can use in this way:

```
// inside the input.forEach callback:
item.addEventListener('keydown',event => {
    var isDotPresent = item.value.indexOf('.')>-1;
    var isDotInput = event.key==='.';

    // I have to avoid the dot:
    if (isDotPresent && isDotInput) {
        // avoid the effect of the event (so the injection of dot into the text)
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one:

```
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

`(\.\d+)?` will assure your decimal fraction will only repeats one time.