# Extract valid numbers from character vector in R

Tags: r, regex, numbers

Suppose I have the below character vector

`c("hi", "4", "-21", "6.5", "7. 5", "-2.2", "4h")`

Now I want to extract only valid numbers which are in the above vector:

`c("4", "-21", "6.5", "-2.2")`

note: one space in between . and 5 in `7. 5` so not a valid number.

I was trying with regex `/^-?(0|[1-9]\\d*)(\\.\\d+)?$/` which is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation) but no luck.

So what would be the regex to extract valid numbers from a character vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grep` that matches digits with `.` from the start (`^`) till the end (`$`) of the string

```
grep("^-?[0-9.]+$", v1, value = TRUE)
[1] "4"    "-21"  "6.5"  "-2.2"
```

Or for fringe cases

```
grep("^[ -]?[0-9]+(\\.\\d+)?$", c(v1, "4.1.1"), value = TRUE)
[1] "4"    "-21"  "6.5"  "-2.2"

grep("^[ -]?[0-9]+(\\.\\d+)?$", c(v1, "4.1.1", " 2.9"), value = TRUE)
[1] "4"    "-21"  "6.5"  "-2.2" " 2.9"
```

Answer (score 4):

`as.numeric` already does a great job of this. Anything that's a valid number can be successfully coerced to numeric, everything else is `NA`.

```
x = c("hi", "4", "-21", "6.5", "7. 5", "-2.2", "4h")
y = as.numeric(x)
y = y[!is.na(y)]
y
# [1]   4.0 -21.0   6.5  -2.2
```