# Regex to replace everything except numbers and a decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text field that needs to remain only text or decimal. Here is the code that I'm currently using to replace everything except numbers and a decimal point. Issue is, I can't figure out a regex that will identify everything else

```
document.getElementById(target).value = newVal.replace(/\D[^\.]/g, "");
```

The \D works fine, but I've tried `(?!.), (?!\.), [^.], [^\.]` and so on...

Any suggestions for a regular expression that identifies positively with anything except a number or a decimal?

Thanks for the help

Comment: in case you're looking to check for actual numbers rather than numeric digits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328875/javascript-regex-to-remove-all-numbers-with-specific-lenght-or-do-a-persistent

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Use this:

```
document.getElementById(target).value = newVal.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
```

Comment: @Hugo this does not allow anything, you should just not pass a string that could potentially contain more decimal points and pre-process it first. It's like saying string allows every character...

Comment: Then run the returned value through parseFloat. That will remove additional decimal points. e.g. `parseFloat("46554.4655465.54654.545345.5") = 46554.4655465`

Comment: This is great to convert already-formatted numbers like money to a computable float.

Comment: with `replace(/[^0-9.\-]/g, '')` you will get negative numbers too

Comment: Moshen, `replace(/[^0-9.\-]/g, '')` is a good start, but allows subtraction formulas, such as -7-8, which will break data systems without server side checking.  The regex must only match the first character for negation.  I will not post the solution on SO because the last regex question and answer I posted was deleted by Sammitch, who, like the new owners of SO, don't understand how SO works (posting questions and answers together), and don't know the definition of the word blog (it's web-log).  So I don't cast my pearls before swine: let the folks who use SO break their data systems.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById(target).value = newVal.replace(/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/, "");
```

Comment: best answer. Removes 0.000
10.000000
.22
2.234, but keeps 1, 10, 10.1, 10.22

Comment: This expression looks complicated, could you explain how it works or what exactly it would remove?

Comment: This doesn't work with cyrillic input such as "5.12 руб."

Comment: "11111".replace(/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/, "") - result empty string

Answer (score 8):

Removing only decimal part can be done as follows:

```
number.replace(/(\.\d+)+/,'');
```

This would convert 13.6667px into 13px (leaving units px untouched).

Answer (score 3):

##### Regular expression syntax cheatsheet

[Go MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet)

```js
const str1 = 'hello 123 !@#$%^WORLD?.456_';
const str2 = '৳ $ 20,500.00';

console.log(str1.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")); //123.456
console.log(str2.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")); //20500.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the link [Regular Expression Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bGkhEg/5)

use the below reg exp

```
[a-z] + [^0-9\s.]+|\.(?!\d)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using replace and search to force a decimal number**

```
(text: string )=>{         
     const index = text.search(/(\.)/);                                              
     if (index != text.length -1) {
        let str = text.substring(0, index+1);
        let end = text.substring(index).replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        text = str + end;
     }
     return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep comma ',' but be converted as '.' then your users will not have problem using both, then use this:

```
event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '').replace(',', '.')
```