# Javascript - Show all telephone numbers in a range

Tags: javascript

If I have phone number ranges such as `5555555555-5599` `5555550000-0003` `5555550005-0007`, my mission is to have it return all results without using a server. Is it possible for it to return without a server a result that would look like:

```
5555555555
5555555556
5555555557
/* etc */
```

My previous post about javascript has helped me up to this point but I wanted to rehaul the whole site.

[Javascript dashes in phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093187/javascript-dashes-in-phone-number)

If you could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. I'm just having a mind block right now if this is even possible.

Comment: Are your phone numbers stored in an array?

Comment: What does it mean: "without a server"?

Comment: It would run via a simple .htm file on the desktop. Not able to do PHP for example.

Comment: The numbers are stored exactly how I put them up there. I would just copy and paste in a textbox or the like.

Comment: I can change the format using excel if that would make it easier for scripting.

Comment: The term you are seeking is "client-side", meaning you want to use the user's browser (via JS) to calculate these values, and not process the data on the server.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a single phone range in the form of "xxxxxxyyyy-zzzz", split the whole string on the dash and the first part of the string at the 6th index. This yields three strings "xxxxxx", "yyyy", and "zzzz". Using a for loop, you can create an array of phone numbers by concatenating the prefix "xxxxxx" onto the range "yyyy"-"zzzz":

```
// Get an array from a given range "xxxxxxyyyy-zzzz"
function fromRange(range) {
  var phoneNumArray = [];
  var prefix = range.substring(0,5);
  var suffixRange = range.split("-");
  for (var suffix = suffixRange[0].substring(4, -1);suffix < suffixRange[1];suffix++) {
    phoneNumArray.push(prefix + suffix);
  }
  return phoneNumArray;
}
```

Try it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81bm5n3o/1/).