# Javascript Remove all charater except leading - , one dot and digits

Tags: javascript, regex

First of all this question is not same as

[strip non-numeric characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-non-numeric-characters-from-string) or

[Regex to replace everything except numbers and a decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572194/regex-to-replace-everything-except-numbers-and-a-decimal-point)

I want to convert a string with valid number like.

```
--1234// will be -1234
-123-123 will be -123123
12.123.3 will be 12.1233
-123.13.123 will be -123.13123
```

I tried those

```
number.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '') //it accepts multiple . and -
number.replace(/[^0-9.]-/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');//it accepts multiple minus
```

I am facing Problem with leading minus sign.

How I can convert a string which will remove all characters except leading -(remove other minus),digits and only one dot(remove other dots)

Comment: I don't think you can do this with regex, you are applying logic to your matches. For instance, you want to concatenate different groups of numbers into one discarding some characters in the middle. Regex is not the tool for doing this.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza I am almost there.Can you help me to write the regex to find all -(minus sign) except first  one.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: I came up with solution to solve the -(minus sign) problem. But `.(decimal)` position cannot be defined by simple rule. Check my answer for explanation.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam, see if my answer helps you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I am sharing my solution.
Lets assume the string is `a`;

```
//this will convert a to positive integer number
b=a.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

//this will convert a to integer number(positive and negative)
b=a.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '').replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');

//this will convert a to positive float number
```

`b=a.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(..*)./g, '$1');`

```
//this will convert a to float number (positive and negative)
```

`b=a.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(..*)./g, '$1').replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');`

### Update for floating number.(solves copy paste problem)

```
//For positive float number
b=a.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace('.', 'x').replace(/\./g,'').replace('x','.');

//For Negative float number
b=a.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace('.', 'x').replace(/\./g,'').replace('x','.').replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');
```

Comment: Last one converts `'1.2.3.4.5'` to `"1.2.3.45"`

Comment: @Atomosk thanks for the example. However I use that expression in input field.When user type one dot they cannot type 2nd dot for that expression,that's why I did not notice that exception.

Comment: What about copying and pasting?

Answer (score 6):

Based on @Shaiful Islam's answer, I added one more code.

```
var value = number
    .replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '')       // remove chars except number, hyphen, point. 
    .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')     // remove multiple points.
    .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '')         // remove middle hyphen.
    .replace(/^0+(\d)/gm, '$1');    // remove multiple leading zeros. <-- I added this.
```

**Result**

```
00.434 => 0.434
```

Comment: It doesn't remove multiple dots.

Answer (score 3):

Not very clean, but works!

```js
var strings = ["-1234","-123-123","12.123.3", "-123.13.123"];
strings.forEach(function(s) {
    var i = 0;
    s = s.replace(/(?!^)-/g, '').replace(/\./g, function(match) { 
        return match === "." ? (i++ === 0 ? '.' : '') : ''; 
    });
    console.log(s);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I got Idea from your answer `number.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1').replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');`

Comment: @ShaifulIslam, glad I could help. Would appreciate if you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data given below,

```
--1234
-123-123
12.123.3
-123.13.123
```

`-`(minus sign or hyphen) causes no problem because it's place is **only** before digits and **not between** digits. So this can be solved using following regex.

**Regex:** `-(?=-)|(?<=\d)-(?=\d+(-\d+)?$)` and replace with `empty` string.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM4bO0/2)**

However, the position of `.`(decimal) cannot be determined. Because `123.13.123` could also mean `123.13123` and `12313.123`.

Comment: Nice but does not work if a minus is added at the end

Answer (score 0):

Without regex, you can map over the characters this way:

```js
// this function takes in one string and return one integer
f=s=>(
    o='',                   // stands for (o)utput
    d=m=p=0,                // flags for: (d)igit, (m)inus, (p)oint
    [...s].map(x=>          // for each (x)char in (s)tring
        x>='0'&x<='9'?      // if is number
            o+=x            // add to `o`
        :x=='-'?            // else if is minus
            m||(p=0,m=o=x)  // only if is the first, reset: o='-';
        :x=='.'?            // else if is point
            p||(p=o+=x)     // add only if is the first point after the first minus
        :0),                // else do nothing
    +o                      // return parseInt(output);
);

['--1234','-123-123','12.123.3','-123.13.123'].forEach(
x=>document.body.innerHTML+='<pre>f(\''+x+'\') -> '+f(x)+'</pre>')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In my favor, I can argue my function runs in `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
number.replace(/[^\d|.-]/g, '') //removes all character except of digits, dot and hypen
      .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '') //removes every hypen except of first position
      .replace(/(\.){2,}/g, '$1') //removes every multiplied dot
```

It should then formatted to the proper locale setting using `Intl.NumberFormat`.

Comment: how about multiple dots?1.2.3

Comment: It doesn't work, because there is no info which dot is decimal separator.