# How to restrict the TextBox to accept only one dot in decimal number in keypress event in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a windows mobile application, in this i want to restrict the asp.net textbox to accept only one dot in decimal number (C#) so please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just register to the [Textbox TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx) event. To validate a decimal number, you could either use a basic [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-decimal-numbers) or [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) method. Both methods are shown below.

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?"))
      TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;

   decimal value;
   if(!decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out value))
      TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with control extenders.  You can

1. Check client side via ajax/javascript to be sure only one decimal is entered, and
2. You can reuse the extender on other textboxes on future forms.