# Accept only one "." in Textbox that is accepting only numeric value

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

How can I accept only one "." in Textbox that is accepting only numeric value?
I am using an ajax tool called **`FilteredTextBoxExtender`**

this is my sample code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMNumberOfHours" runat="server" 
Width="50px" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" 
 FilterType="Numbers, Custom" ValidChars="." 
 TargetControlID="txtMNumberOfHours" ></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

in this code, I can enter multiple "." which is not good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761965/how-to-restrict-the-textbox-to-accept-only-one-dot-in-decimal-number-in-keypress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using regexvalidator or maskededit extender?

With maskededitextender you can do

```
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" 
   runat="server" TargetControlID="txtMNumberOfHours"
   Mask="99.99" MaskType="Number" InputDirection="RightToLeft" />
```

This will allow numbers with total four digits, 2 on left and 2 on right of dot.

Answer (score 1):

FilteredTextBoxExtender only looks at one character at a time as they're being entered so it's not looking at the whole thing to see how many periods have been entered.

I'd suggest using RegularExpressionValidator.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is to check the string for any extra .'s using RegEx as I am not a RegEx Expert by no means I'll leave that to another member. But you would do a check in the OnTextChanged Event on the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this in asp.net is to write some custom javascript validation.

You can use the following reg-ex to validate the value.

```
^[-]?((\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)|(\.\d+))$
```

If you use jQuery, you could use the [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event to validate at client side.

Ofcourse, you should always parse it again at the server side and not assume the client side will give you correct data.

Answer (score -1):

this is the solution

```
 <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtPrice_Filter" runat="server" BehaviorID="txtPrice_Filter" FilterType="Custom, Numbers" TargetControlID="txtPrice" ValidChars="." />
```