# How do I parse "N/A - -0.09%" and extract the number after the first hyphen in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, string, parsing

Here's my string: "N/A - -0.09%"   (the double quotes are included and part of the string I want to dissect)

Here's my code:

```
$url = 'abc123.php';    
$data = file_get_contents($url);  //$data contains "N/A - -0.09%" (the string to parse)

$regex = '/""/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match);
```

How do I isolate everything after the first hyphen, but before the % sign?

I know for a fact that the string will ALWAYS have "  "N/A - " in front, and I only want to extract the number with its negative sign if it's negative.

I want to assign the number -0.09 to a variable.  The number may be positive or negative.  If it's positive there will be no hypen, eg. 0.123.  If it's negative there will be a second hyphen in addition to the first, eg. -2.5 .

Please help me formulate the regex part to isolate -0.09 into a variable, say $number.  THANK YOU SO!

Comment: Why not you ensure abc123.php to return an exact double value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

Comment: ajreal...the source of the data is from another website whose formatting I cannot control.  So i need to work with that string.

Comment: Try `<?php
foreach (array(0x52,0x54,0x46,0x4d) as $search)
{
    echo chr($search);
}
echo "\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regex here, I'd just remove the two quotes (replacing `"` with nothing using [str_replace()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)), then split the string into words (using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with ' ' as the delimiter), then grab the last "word" using [array_pop()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php).

```
url = 'abc123.php';    
$data = file_get_contents($url);  //$data contains "N/A - -0.09%" (the string to parse)

$match = array_pop(explode(' ', str_replace("\"", '', $data)));
echo $match . "\n";
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the helpful comment.  I didn't know about explode and array_pop().  This does EXACTLY what I was looking for and I learned 2 new things.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Ben, I had a followup question about the output.  I get this: string(6) "-0.09%".  How do I remove the string(6) and double quotes and percentage sign surrounding the number I want (in this case it's -0.09).

Comment: That's just because you are using `var_dump`. That's not what you want. var_dump is a structured output. If you just want to output the string, use `echo`.

Comment: I updated my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Ben..I see what you mean now.  Thank you for your help!