# Average numbers in character string in R

Tags: r, character, mean

I have a column in a data frame that looks something like this:

`[1] [0.50 .. 0.52]    [0.52 .. 0.54]    [0.54 .. 0.56]    [0.56 .. 0.58]

  [5] [0.58 .. 0.60]    [0.60 .. 0.62]    [0.62 .. 0.64]    [0.64 .. 0.66]

  [9] [0.66 .. 0.68]    [0.68 .. 0.70]    [0.70 .. 0.72]    [0.72 .. 0.74]

 [13] [0.74 .. 0.76]    [0.76 .. 0.78]    [0.78 .. 0.80]    [0.80 .. 0.82]`

I would like to take the average of the two numbers in this column. However, I don't know how to go about this. I tried using gsub() to replace the " .. " but I cannot remove the brackets, and I cannot seem to find a way to just extract the numbers. What would be the best way to just get the average of these numbers?

Comment: Could you give the result of the function `dput` on your data for us to work on it ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gsub` to take out the brackets (remembering to double escape for them), then use `strsplit` to separate the numbers, and `sapply` to work on the resulting list with `mean` and `as.numeric`:

```
x <- c("[0.52 .. 0.54]", "[0.54 .. 0.56]")

sapply(strsplit(gsub("[\\[\\]]","",x,perl=T)," .. "),function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
[1] 0.53 0.55
```

Comment: (+1) Exactly the approach I would have taken.

Comment: Actually, not exactly--I had done `[^[:digit:]. ]` for my `gsub` instead.

Comment: Nice approach...short, compact and good use of the list structure

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **base** functions for regex in R (gsub, regexp, ...) or the **stringr** package to that (**str_extract**).

```
require(stringr)

string <- c("[0.50 .. 0.52]", "[0.52 .. 0.54]", "[0.54 .. 0.56]", "[0.56 .. 0.58]")

number <- as.numeric(str_extract(string, "\\d\\.\\d+"))
number
[1] 0.50 0.52 0.54 0.56
```

You can then compute the mean between 1 and 2,  3 and 4, using for the **rollmean** function in **zoo**

```
require(zoo)
average <- rollmean(number, 2)
average[as.logical(seq_along(average) %%2 )]
[1] 0.51 0.55
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! Just curious though, what does "\\d\\.\\d+" do?

Comment: "\\d\\.\\d+" is a regular expression for decimal number ( 8.6767 or 7.5 works but not 70.45). Example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

Answer (score 3):

Use `gsub` to replace the special characters with spaces. Then `strsplit` and take the `mean`:

First Replicate the data:

```
x <- scan(what="character", quote='"', sep=" ", text='"[0.50 .. 0.52]" "[0.52 .. 0.54]" "[0.54 .. 0.56]" "[0.56 .. 0.58]" "[0.58 .. 0.60]" "[0.60 .. 0.62]" "[0.62 .. 0.64]" "[0.64 .. 0.66]" "[0.66 .. 0.68]" "[0.68 .. 0.70]" "[0.70 .. 0.72]" "[0.72 .. 0.74]" "[0.74 .. 0.76]" "[0.76 .. 0.78]" "[0.78 .. 0.80]" "[0.80 .. 0.82]"')
```

Then use `gsub` with `sapply` and `mean`:

```
xx <- gsub("\\[|\\.\\.|\\]", "", x)
sapply(strsplit(xx, "  "), function(x)mean(as.numeric(x)))
```

The results:

```
 [1] 0.51 0.53 0.55 0.57 0.59 0.61 0.63 0.65 0.67 0.69 0.71 0.73 0.75 0.77 ...
```

---

The regular expression works like this:

- The brackets `[  ]` means replace any text inside the brackets
- You want to replace brackets `[` and `]` but since these have meaning in regex, you need to escape these, i.e. `\\[` and `\\]`
- Finally the `|` means the same as logical `OR`, i.e. find me brackets OR double periods

You can read more about regular expresions in R at `?regexp` or `?gsub`.

Comment: @user1537589 I have edited the answer. Does it now make sense?