# Regex expression in javascript to validate number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

HI i need to validate a number using  regex. The main idea is that i have the integer part, the decimal part and the decimal separator of a number. For example if i have this:

```
var integer_part = 4;
var decimal_part = 2;
var decimal_separator = ".";

// will be valid numbers
// 2546.33 
// 12
// 1.33
// 263
// 0
```

can i make a regex string with the values in the variables to validate a string ¿?

Comment: Try this - `\d+(\.\d+)?`

Comment: Similar post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

Comment: what have you tried? what's the problem? also, in what way are the assignments relevant?

Comment: @RohitJain looks like an answer to me. add it before someone beats you!

Comment: Why do you need the variables?

Comment: @lbstr.. There is absolutely no regret for being beaten for answer like this, which must be having so much of duplicates on SO only.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regex for this:

```
!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
```

That checks a number is a float, isn't NaN and isn't infinity.

This sounds like an XY problem. What you should have asked is `How can I validate a number?` and left the regex part out.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not clear from your question, I am assuming you want to use the variables to determine the range of allowable values in your regex  If so, you can make your pattern string like this:

```
pattern = '/[\d]{0,' + integer_part + '}(' + decimal_separator + '[\d]{1,' + decimal_part + '})?/';
```

This is a basic implementation. In this case, in order to use `.` as you separator you would actually want to set `decimal_separator = '\.';` This is to escape the decimal which is wildcard match in regex.

If you really want to look for more edge cases, you might want to build up your pattern conditionally like this:

```
pattern = '/[\d]{0,' + integer_part + '}';
if (decimal_part > 0) {
    if (decimal_separator == '.') {
        pattern += '(\.';
    } else {
        pattern +=  '(' + decimal_separator;
    }
    pattern += '[\d]';
    if (decimal_part == 1) {
         pattern += '{1}';
    } else {
         pattern += '{1,' + decimal_part + '}';
    }
    pattern += ')?';
}
pattern += '/';
```

Comment: `.` has special treatment in regex, escape it

Comment: @hoaz I did in my more detailed implementation.  Just noticed I actuall typed over my note to use `\.` as decimal separator in case of first string when updating to add the more detailed implementation.  Will add it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this regex, it will look for anything with

```
\d+(\.\d+)
```

However, there might be a better way to do it.

```
Boolean isFloat=false;
try
{
   float num=parseFloat(n);
   isFloat=!isNaN(num) && isFinite(num);
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex)
{
   //Isn't a number
}
```

Comment: Typed variables? Have you been using too much Java?