# Javascript Regex for decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, I am trying to validate a user input to be only valid decimals

I have the following JSFiddle that shows the regex I currently have

http://jsfiddle.net/FCHwx/

```
var regex = /^[0-9]+$/i;

var key = '500.00';

if (key.match(regex) != null) {
    alert('legal');
}
else {
    alert('illegal');
}
```

This works fine for integers. I need to also allow decimal numbers (i.e. up to 2 decimal places)

I have tried many of the regex's that can be found on stackoverflow
e.g.
[Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

but none of them work for this use case

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question you linked to seems to do exactly what you want.  Can you explain why those don't work, including showing the input that they fail on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be work

```
var regex = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/i;
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to - try it in the jsfiddle above

Comment: @ChrisCa [yes it does](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/StH4F/). Besides, [108 StackOverflow users can't be wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/308124/356541), can they? ;)

Comment: the one you link to works - it is slightly different to the one above (it has a /i on the end which seems to do the trick - thanks

Comment: @ChrisCa the `i` modifier has no influence here, it changes letters to match case independent, no letters, no influence on the regex.

Comment: yeah - i did try that one - I even linked to it in the question. but it needs a little tweak to work in my use case (the /i).

Comment: @ChrisCa, for me it makes no difference (as it should) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCHwx/8/)

Comment: the reg ex linked to in the other question  doesn't have the trailing slash that your jsfiddle has - that seems to be the problem

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
var regex = /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{0,2}$/i;
```

Comment: you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` too, it don't think it makes much difference, but I think it is a good practise to use those predefined character classes

Comment: This would allow also "1." as valid input.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to not use REGEX for this, but use a simple `!isNaN`:

```
console.log(!isNaN('20.13')); // true
console.log(!isNaN('20')); // true
console.log(!isNaN('20kb')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\d+(\.\d{1,2})?
```

d is for digit
d{1,2} is for 1 digit before . and at least 2 digits such as 0.51

Comment: the 3 means 3 decimals, he wants only 2.

Comment: right, thought it meant 3 chars in total minimum