# Restrict to numeric values rather than integer values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I restrict input fields to numeric values rather than integer values?

```
<input type="text" class="numericOnly">
```

jQ

```
$(".numericOnly").keypress(function (e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^0-9]/g)) return false;
});
```

Comment: You should find the regex for decimal values here ;o) http://stackoverflow.com/a/15134885/1370442

Comment: Why don't u try .isNumeric() function to check...?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/

Comment: @DeDevelopers thanks. I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow decimal points, add them to the character class you're using. E.g. `/[^0-9.]/g` if a decimal point in your locale is `.`, or `/[^0-9,]/g` if it's `,` (as it is in some).

Of course, that would let someone type `.0.0.0.1`, you'll want whole-value checks on the field as well as keystroke-level checks.

Separately, remember there are lots of ways for values to get into fields other than typing (pasting, for instance), so (again) whole-value checks at some stage will be a good idea.

---

Side note: Use `e.which`, not `e.keyCode`. jQuery [normalizes the event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), setting `e.which` on browsers that don't set it natively.

Comment: Thanks for the extra bit of info. Your suggestion works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".numericOnly").keypress(function(e) {

    var code = e.which;

    if(($(this).val().indexOf(".") == -1 && code == 46) || (code >= 48 && code <= 57) || (code == 51) || (code == 8) || (code >= 37 && code <= 40))
    {
        return true;
    }       

    return false;
})

.bind("paste",function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

## With Dot

Get this js file

http://thefitties.co.uk/js/plugins/jquery-numeric.js

And

In HTML

```
<input class="numeric" type="text">
```

in Script

```
$("input.numeric").numeric()
```

## WITHOUT DOt

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

OR

http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/