# Regex for number with decimals and thousand separator

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal

I need regex to validate a number that could contain thousand separators or decimals using javascript.
Max value being `9,999,999.99`
Min value `0.01`
Other valid values:
`11,111`
`11.1`
`1,111.11`

INVALID values:
`1111`
`1111,11`
`,111`
`111,`

I've searched all over with no joy.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
/^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/
```

About the minimum and maximum values... Well, I wouldn't do it with a regex, but you can add lookaheads at the beginning:

```
/^(?!0+\.00)(?=.{1,9}(\.|$))\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/
```

Note: this allows `0,999.00`, so you may want to change it to:

```
/^(?!0+\.00)(?=.{1,9}(\.|$))(?!0(?!\.))\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/
```

which would not allow a leading 0.

**Edit:**
Tests: http://jsfiddle.net/pKsYq/2/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Loamhoof
No joy though. I'm calling it like this and it fails:
var re = new RegExp("/(?!0+\.00)(?!.{10,}\.)(?!0,?\d)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d+/");
if (!min.match(re)) {
alert('No match');
}

Comment: @Swifty could you give me an example of what fails?

Comment: I'm using this page to test it: [Regular Expression Tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) If I enter '1' it fails.

Comment: @Swifty my bad, I thought the decimals were required. I'm changing it.

Comment: which one did you change? the bottom one in your main post stil fails, '1' should also match

Comment: It does for me. I'll add an example.

Comment: Do you use the same test page as I do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pKsYq/ though it seems there's a problem with `0` values. Fixing that.

Comment: Where do I see the output?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would log to the results window. Didn't think of checking the dev console. Thanks

Comment: Seems to very close to what I need, yet these ones are failing that should pass: '9,999,999.99', '0,01'

Comment: `0,01` should not, `0.01` works. I've found the origin of the problem for `9,999,999.99`, working on it.

Comment: @Swifty that should do it.

Comment: Typo, my bad. I found another one that doesn't work that should: '777,777.00'

Comment: @Swifty same problem as before, check the last version.

Comment: @RyanDaulton the question specified a max value of `9,999,999.99`, which is lower than `10,029,589.84`.

Comment: @Loamhoof The expression fails for value 99,999,999. Please fix it

Answer (score 4):

```
((\d){1,3})+([,][\d]{3})*([.](\d)*)?
```

It worked on a few, but I'm still learning regex as well.

The logic should be 1-3 digits 0-1 times, 1 comma followed by 3 digits any number of times, and a single . followed by any number of digits 0-1 times

Comment: No joy there either Munch.

Comment: can you give the fail cases?

Comment: edited, should have been a + instead of ? for first subexpression.

Comment: somehow that returns everything as valid?

Comment: @Swifty * and ? equate to optional, and \d{1,3}+ equates to at least 1 digit. Without surrounding this in ^ and $, it is equivalent to "contains at least 1 digit"

Answer (score 3):

First, I want to point out that if you own the form the data is coming from, the best way to restrict the input is to use the proper form elements (aka, number field)

```
<input type="number" name="size" min="0.01" max="9,999,999.99" step="0.01">
```

Whether ","  can be entered will be based on the browser, but the browser will always give you the value as an actual number. (Remember that all form data must be validated/sanitized server side as well. Never trust the client)

---

Second, I'd like to expand on the other answers to a more robust (platform independent)/modifiable regex.

- You should surround the regex with ^ and $ to make sure you are matching against the whole number, not just a subset of it. ex `^<my_regex>$`
- The right side of the decimal is optional, so we can put it in an optional group `(<regex>)?`
- Matching a literal period and than any chain of numbers is simply `\.\d+`

  - If you want to insist the last number after the decimal isn't a 0, you can use `[1-9]` for "a non-zero number" so `\.\d+[1-9]`
- For the left side of the decimal, the leading number will be non-zero, or the number is zero. So `([1-9]<rest-of-number-regex>|0)`
- The first group of numbers will be 1-3 digits so `[1-9]\d{0,2}`
- After that, we have to add digits in 3s so `(,\d{3})*`

  - Remember ? means optional, so to make the , optional is just `(,?\d{3})*`

Putting it all together

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})*|0)(\.\d+[1-9])?$
```

Comment: This is still very relevant in 2022. It helped fixing my problem with thousand separator. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In a recent project we needed to alter this version in order to meet international requirements.
This is what we used: `^-?(\d{1,3}(?<tt>\.|\,| ))((\d{3}\k<tt>)*(\d{3}(?!\k<tt>)[\.|\,]))?\d*$`

Creating a named group `(?<tt>\.|\,| )` allowed us to use the negative look ahead `(?!\k<tt>)[\.|\,])` later to ensure the thousands separator and the decimal point are in fact different.

Answer (score 2):

Tezra's formula fails for '1.' or '1.0'. For my purposes, I allow leading and trailing zeros, as well as a leading + or - sign, like so:

```
^[-+]?((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|(\d*))(\.|\.\d*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below regrex for following retrictions -

```
^(?!0|\.00)[0-9]+(,\d{3})*(.[0-9]{0,2})$
```

1. Not allow 0 and .00.
2. ','(thousand seperator) after 3 digits.
3. '.' (decimal upto 2 decimal places).