# Validating Positive number with comma and period

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, expression

I need a regular expression validation expression that will

**ALLOW**

- positive number(0-9)
- `,` and `.`

**DISALLOW**

- letter(a-z)
- any other letter or symbol except `.` and `,`

for example, on my asp.net text box, if I type `anything@!#--`, the regular expression validation will disallow it, if I type `10.000,50` or `10,000.50` it should allowed.

I've been trying to use this regex:

```
^\d+(\.\d\d)?$
```

but my textbox also must allow `,` symbol and I tried using only integer regex validation, it did disallow if I type string, but it also disallow `.` and `,` symbol while it should allow number(0-9) and also `.` and `,` symbol

Comment: `.` is special symbol in regex, you should backslash it `\.`

Comment: this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148034/regex-for-number-with-decimals-and-thousand-seperator

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/matching-numbers-with-regular-expressions-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
(?:\d|[,\.])+
```

OR

```
^(?:\d|[,\.])+$
```

It matches one or more numbers or `,` or `.` one or more times.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uF7mO3)

Comment: matches `54۳۲١८৮੪૯୫୬१७੩௮௫౫೮൬൪๘໒໕២៧៦`

Answer (score 4):

**Don't Use `\d` to match `[0-9]` in `.NET`**

First off, in .NET, `\d` will match any digits in any script, such as:

```
654۳۲١८৮੪૯୫୬१७੩௮௫౫೮൬൪๘໒໕២៧៦᠖
```

So you really want to be using `[0-9]`

**Incomplete Spec**

You say you want to only allow "digits, commas and periods", but I don't think that's the whole spec. That would be `^[0-9,.]+$`, and that would match

```
...,,,
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/yP2kA0).

**Tweaking the Spec**

It's hard to guess what you really want to allow: would `10,1,1,1` be acceptable?

We could start with something like this, to get some fairly well-formed strings:

```
^(?:[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:(?:\.[0-9]{3})*|(?:,[0-9]{3})*)(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$
```

Play with [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/pX5aP2), see what should and shouldn't match... When you are sure about the final spec, we can tweak the regex.

**Sample Matches:**

```
0
12
12.123
12,12
12,123,123
12,123,123.12456
12.125.457.22
```

**Sample Non-Matches:**

```
12,
123.
1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Ha, and I thought I'd be the first one to point out the `^[0-9,.]+$` thing lol

Comment: @Jerry No my friend, I was quite surprised when I got to the question and saw the 4 answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this one (starts with digit, ends with digit):

```
(\d+[\,\.])*\d+
```

If you need more sophisticated price Regex you should use:

```
(?:(?:[1-9]\d?\d?([ \,\.]?\d{3})*)|0)(?:[\.\,]\d+)?
```

**Edit:** To make it more reliable (and dont get 00.50) you can add starting and ending symbol check:

```
(^|\s)(?:(?:[1-9]\d?\d?([ \,\.]?\d{3})*)|0)(?:[\.\,]\d+)($|\s)?
```

Comment: matches `54۳۲١८৮੪૯୫୬१७੩௮௫౫೮൬൪๘໒໕២៧៦`

Answer (score 0):

Your format is a bit strange as it is not a standard format.
My first thought was to put a float instead of a string and put a Range validation attribute to avoid negative number.
But because of formatting, not sure it would work.
Another way is the regex, of course.
The one you propose means :
"some numbers then possibly a group formed by a dot and two numbers exactly". 
This is not what you exepected.

Strictly fitted your example of a number lower than 100,000.99 one regex could be :
`^[0-9]{1-2}[\.,][0-9]{3}([\.,][0-9]{1-2})?$`
A more global regex, that accept all positive numbers is the one posted by Avinash Raj : `(?:\d|[,\.])+`

Comment: which one? I replace the `\d` shortcut by [0-9] in my first regex. Should be ok.

Comment: Nice that you fixed the `54۳۲١८৮੪૯୫୬१७੩௮௫౫೮൬൪๘໒໕២៧៦` problem. :) But there are serious problems remaining in your `^[0-9]{1-2}[\.,]` etc, as you will discover if you test it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best regex for your condition will be :

```
^[\d]+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

this will validate whatever you like

and at the same time:

not validate:

- numbers ending in ,
- numbers ending in .
- numbers having . before comma
- numbers having more than one decimal points

check out the demo here : http://regex101.com/r/zI0mJ4

Comment: matches `54۳۲١८৮੪૯୫୬१७੩௮௫౫೮൬൪๘໒໕២៧៦`