# Regex in javascript to allow only numbers, commas, and a single decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently i am using this regex to match for positive numbers with a single decimal point

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

But this doesn't allow commas. How can i modify this to allow zero or more commas before the decimal point?

Example :

- 11,111.00 (should be allowed)
  I am okay with numbers having any number of comma's before decimal point.

EDIT:

Valid values

- 111
- 11,111
- 11,111.0
- 111111

The values can be entered with or without comma.
The datatype of this field is SQL MONEY, so it will handle comma's.

Comment: Like [`/^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/oHVe7e/2)? Or [`/^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/oHVe7e/1)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for number with decimals and thousand separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148034/regex-for-number-with-decimals-and-thousand-separator)

Comment: The solution in the above question does nort match `11111111111.55`. Prayag, do you need a common regex to match values like `55555.87` and `12,567.78`? Or is `/^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/` enough?

Comment: [after edit] So, does it mean you need `^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need

```
/^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oHVe7e/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)` - Either of:

  - `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` - 1 to 3 digits followed with 0+ sequences of a `,` and 3 digits
  - `|`  - or
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

```js
var strs = [',,,,', '111', '11,111', '11,111.0', '111111'];
var re = /^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s + " => " + re.test(s));
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but it doesn't allow, say `10,00,00,000` which is a valid grouping of digits for India.

Comment: @vlaz: In that case, [`{3}` should be changed to `+`](https://regex101.com/r/oHVe7e/4).

Comment: Tested it against [this dataset](https://regex101.com/r/Hwhz5i/1), by the way and it's otherwise really good. It's just the annoying groupings that (as usual) are annoying.

Comment: @vlaz Agreed with your point regarding Indian groupings. But i am not looking for Indian groupings in my regex[But yes, I am an Indian :)], its for the American numbering system.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very simple general solution, without any assumptions about how many digits are needed.

```
/^\d[\d,]*(\.\d+)?$/
```

`[\d,]` will match digits or commas.
You could make the regex more complicated if you really need it to be more specific.

Comment: Just a word of warning, this will also allow stuff like `100,,00.12` but I am not sure if that is a concern.

Comment: This will validate `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,` and I bet this is a concern.

Comment: Well, yes. OP really needs to clarify what he needs.

Comment: @vlaz 100,,00.12 is not a concern.
But ,,,, definitely should not be matched, as i need a valid number

Comment: In that case just add a `\d` to the start.

Comment: Now `1.00` is invalid.

Comment: Honestly, I just wanted to explain what `[\d,]` means.  I'm not trying to do the OP's job for him

Comment: `return /^[\d,]*\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(value); ` // Allow comma separated digits (Currency format) and '.' only, using a RegExp

Answer (score 1):

I would use this

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|\d+|\d{2}(?:,\d{2})*,\d{3})(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See [demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/X40vBl/3)

Comment: Preforms [pretty well|https://regex101.com/r/X40vBl/2]. Indian numbers again but they may or may not be a of concern.

Comment: how would `10,00,00,000` be valid @vlaz?

Comment: International support. It's a valid grouping of digits in India, for example - if a number is big, the grouping character is placed every _two_ digts, aside from the last group of digits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system

Comment: I've had to deal with internationalised formats, so I know how much of a pain it can be. As I said, though, this may or might not be a problem - depends on the use case. The format expected is already not "international-friendly" as it expects `,` to be the digit separator and `.` to be the decimal separator when those could be swapped or different symbols altogether depending on the locale. I still included the Indian numbers in my testing set as a bit of a curve ball.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty hard to read but I'll explain it

`/^(?:\d+)(?:(?:\d+)|(?:(?:,\d+)?))+(?:\.\d+)?$/`

All the `?:` are just to explicitly say to the regex engine "Don't capture the following group matched by this paren).

The simplified version would be

`/^(\d+)((\d+)|((,\d+)?))+(\.\d+)?$/`

But it'd capture a lot of matching groups for no reason so I removed them