# Match number with thousand separators with a matching pattern before the pattern using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex to match numbers with thousand separators, but only if they are preceded with a `-$`

For example, I would like to match

```
-$1,200
-$750
```

But not

```
$1200
$750
```

From other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148034/regex-for-number-with-decimals-and-thousand-separator), I'm able to use `[0-9]{1,3}` to match numbers with thousand separators, but I can't figure out how to limit to only cases that are preceded with `-$`. `-\$[0-9]{1,3}` doesn't work.

Example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9HM1qw/1)

```
The particular string that I'm trying to get it to work on:
{"amount":1242,"amountFormatted":"-$1,242","currency":"USD","type":"PRICING","__typename":"PriceItem"},{"localizedTitle":"Fees","localizedExplanation":"This fee covers: "}
```

Comment: What language or Regex flavor are you using?

Comment: would like to make it work on regex101. example https://regex101.com/r/9HM1qw/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for number with decimals and thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148034/regex-for-number-with-decimals-and-thousand-separator)

Comment: It's a different question because it asks about matching a pattern before the number

Comment: By SO standards, I think it'd still be considered a duplicate, as the underlying premise is still the same. The changes required to get the solutions listed on that question working in this context are minimal.

Comment: I showed an example of the minimal changes I believed are necessary and how it doesn't provide a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do the trick: `^-\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$` Between the start and end of the line, it first looks for `-$` literally, then 1-3 digits, and then groups a comma and 3 digits, capturing this group as many times as needed.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/jSf4wT/3/)

EDIT: If you want to match between quote marks, as suggested by Bohemian, this regex is likely what you want: `"-\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*"` - it behaves just as the other, but searches between quote marks, instead of between the start and end of the string.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/jSf4wT/4)

Comment: This works! Do you know why it does not work on this particular string? `{"amount":1242,"amountFormatted":"-$1,242","currency":"USD","type":"PRICING","__typename":"PriceItem"},{"localizedTitle":"Fees","localizedExplanation":"This fee covers: "} `

Comment: @Harry It doesn't match because you didn't ask it to match *within a string*, you asked for the *whole* string to match - there are start and end anchors in this answer. You could possibly replace `^` and `$` with `"` and see if it works for you.

Comment: @HarryM see updated answer - looks like it should match your requirements.