# Regular expression in Java for parsing money

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for are regex for parsing money amounts. The String `s10` should not match. Can someone help, or can someone simplify the regex? That's my try:

```java
    public static String[] getMoney(String s) {
        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        String regex = "((\\d{1,3}[.,]?)(\\d{3}[.,]?)*[.,]\\d{1,2})(\\D|$)";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);
        while (mat.find()) {
            ret.add(mat.group(1));
        }
        return ret.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "0,1"; // should match
        String s2 = ",1"; // should not match
        String s3 = "1,"; // should not match
        String s4 = "1.234,01"; // should match
        String s5 = "1234,10"; // should match
        String s6 = "1234,100"; // should not match
        String s7 = "1234,10a"; // should match
        String s8 = "123,456,789.10"; // should match
        String s9 = "123.456.789,10"; // should match
        String s10 = "123,456.789,10"; // should not match (!)

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s1)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s2)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s3)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s4)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s5)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s6)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s7)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s8)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s9)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMoney(s10)));
    }
```

Comment: Why this `String s7 = "1234,10a";` should match ?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148034/regex-for-number-with-decimals-and-thousand-separator solve your problem? (possible duplicate)

Comment: @ikos23 Because there is a String, that contains a valid amount of money.

Comment: So, you do not want to match a number without a fractional part, right? The two digits after a decimal separator must be present?

Comment: @hradecek The regex from Loamhoof's answer only matches point separated values...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Only a point or a semicolon as fractional part separator should must be present.

Comment: Do you want to match  `String s11 = "50";`? `String s12 = "50000";`? `String s13 = "1234,1";`

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a regex? If this is for work, you may want to use an actual parser, e.g. coming from a library like Joda-Money: https://www.joda.org/joda-money/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use

```
(?<![\d,.])(?:\d{1,3}(?:(?=([.,]))(?:\1\d{3})*)?|\d+)(?:(?!\1)[.,]\d{1,2})?(?![,.\d])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b6G4fx/1)

**Details**

- `(?<![\d,.])` - no digit, `.` or `,` allowed immediately on the left
- `(?:\d{1,3}(?:(?=([.,]))(?:\1\d{3})*)?|\d+)` -

  - `\d{1,3}(?:(?=([.,]))(?:\1\d{3})*)?` - one, two or three digits followed with an optional occurrence of a position followed with a comma or dot followed with 0 or more occurrences of the captured value and then any three digits
  - `|\d+` - or 1 or more digits
- `(?:(?!\1)[.,]\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of a comma or dot, but not the same char as in Group 1, and then 1 or 2 digits
- `(?![,.\d])` - no digit, `.` or `,` allowed immediately on the right

In Java, do not forget to double the backslashes:

```
String regex = "(?<![\\d,.])(?:\\d{1,3}(?:(?=([.,]))(?:\\1\\d{3})*)?|\\d+)(?:(?!\\1)[.,]\\d{1,2})?(?![,.\\d])";
```

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew, i have to understand that, because it's not immediately understandable for me, and than that could be the solution.