# Flutter: FilteringTextInputFormatter allow only numbers with 2 decimals

Tags: regex, flutter

I use this:

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
  RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d{0,2})'),
)
```

And it works fine but I cannot use comma, only dots. For some currencies the dot is used to separate thousands and the comma for the decimals.

How could I accept both?

Comment: I think this is a Regex question, not a Flutter one. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16148034/9997212) helps.

Comment: Perhaps like this? `\b\d{1,3}(?:([.,])\d{3})*(?:(?!\1)[.,]\d{2})?\b` https://regex101.com/r/0ItMqg/1

Comment: with that I cannot type either commas or dots. Maybe I pasted it wrong? RegExp(r'^\d{1,3}(?:([.,])\d{3})*(?:(?!\1)[.,]\d{2})?')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `deny` constructor at the beginning and replace `,` with `.`:

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(',', replacementString: '.')
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d{0,2})')),
  ],
)
```

If you need to keep the system separator by https://pub.dev/packages/intl, you can pre-define it and then use it in `RegExp`

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:intl/number_symbols_data.dart' show numberFormatSymbols;

...

String locale = '${ui.window.locale.languageCode}_${ui.window.locale.countryCode}';
if (!numberFormatSymbols.keys.contains(locale))
  locale = ui.window.locale.languageCode;
final separator = numberFormatSymbols[locale]?.DECIMAL_SEP ?? '.';

...

TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('(^\\d*$separator?\\d{0,2})')),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I cannot deny either . or , because that depends on the language

Comment: My corrected answer may help in your task, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: u gangsta bro !