# Getting the first ( i.e. lowest) value from a 'range' of value e.g. £25 - £30

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have here some JS code for getting either a singular value or, if there's a 'range' of prices separated by ' - ', getting the **highest** value:

```
function getPrice() {
  var str = ("£25 - £36");

  var val;
  if (str.indexOf('-') > -1) {
    val = Number(str.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, "").split('-')[1], 10);
  } else {
    val = Number(str.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, "").split('-')[0], 10);
  }
  return val;
}
```

How would I modify this so that it gets the **lowest** value instead?

This 'range' will *always* be either in the format of £25 or £13 - £72 and it will *always* be in pounds. The highest value will *always* be the last; in this context they are functionally the same.

Comment: _"...getting the highest value"_ - Only if the range will always be `<lower bound> - <higher bound>`

Comment: What's the actual problem here? `getPrice()` is not that complicated in what it does. The "mechanic" to get the _"highest value"_ is just an index... (in fact, just get rid of the "range" part)

Comment: As Andreas says, this gets the **last** value, regardless of whether it's actually the largest, if the order can vary then you will probably want to take a slightly different approach after splitting your string.

Comment: Is this always going to be in pounds? Can the pound sign be on the other side? Is the input always going to be `£value` or `£value - £value`?

Comment: I have updated the question the confirm that this 'range' will always be in this format @Andreas

Comment: That's nice of you. But there's still no indication of research or your attempt to solve this on your own. As I've written in my second comment, `getPrice()` is really not complicated in what it does. And with those added restrictions on the possible input its really just a matter of removing code...

Comment: @nickzoum The value will always be in pounds in the format given

Comment: If it's always in this format, then what does your code actually do?  It says:  if there's a `-` then get the second number... so change it to get the first instead of the second.  Are you saying you don't know what `[1]` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve what you require would be to use a Regex to pull out all the figures in the string. You can then apply those matches to `Math.min` to find the lowest one.

The benefit of this approach is that it will retrieve the lowest number regardless of its position in the string.

```js
function getLowestPrice(input) {
  let amounts = input.match(/\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?/g);
  amounts = amounts.map(v => v.replace(',', '')); // remove comma grouping
  return Math.min.apply(this, amounts);
}

console.log(getLowestPrice('£25 - £36')); // = 25
console.log(getLowestPrice('£1,090.99 - £77.25')); // = 77.25
```

*Edit* - I just expanded the Regex to handle values containing thousands grouping and decimals, credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16148273/519413) for that.