# regular expression on asp.net textbox

Tags: regex

Hi I am creating a regular expression that should allow 1 or more digits to be entered, and only 2 digits after an optional period(.) It should not allow letters or any other keys.

So for example it should allow:
`4 
44444
44.44`

and prevent 
`a
% 
44.4444
.44`

I have `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9][0-9]` so far but it does not allow me to enter a single digit only. Everything else is fine. has anyone any suggestions im a newbie and hoping its something simple?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

Answer (score 0):

```
[-+]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{2})?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_hFddctkf--2VsRv)